# How do you retrieve items from a dictionary in the order that they're inserted?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to retrieve items from a Python dictionary in the order that they were inserted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why dictionary values aren't in the inserted order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061380/why-dictionary-values-arent-in-the-inserted-order)

Comment: This question (and outdated accepted answer) is still the #1 result of googling "python dict items by insertion order". If you're reading this, please upvote Brian's 2018 answer.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The standard Python `dict` does this by default if you're using CPython 3.6+ (or Python 3.7+ for any other implementation of Python).

On older versions of Python you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects).

Answer (score 27):

As of Python 3.7, the standard dict preserves insertion order. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

So, you should be able to iterate over the dictionary normally or use `popitem()`.

Comment: Lets get this answer upvoted.  Additionally from the docs, section 5.5 Dictionaries: "Performing list(d) on a dictionary returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in insertion order (if you want it sorted, just use sorted(d) instead)."

Answer (score 20):

Use OrderedDict(), available since version 2.7

Just a matter of curiosity:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a = {}
b = OrderedDict()
c = OrderedDict()

a['key1'] = 'value1'
a['key2'] = 'value2'

b['key1'] = 'value1'
b['key2'] = 'value2'

c['key2'] = 'value2'
c['key1'] = 'value1'

print a == b  # True
print a == c  # True
print b == c  # False
```

Answer (score 17):

The other answers are correct; it's not possible, but you could write this yourself.  However, in case you're unsure how to actually implement something like this, here's a complete and working implementation that subclasses dict which I've just written and tested. (Note that the order of values passed to the constructor is undefined but will come before values passed later, and you could always just not allow ordered dicts to be initialized with values.)

```
class ordered_dict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._order = self.keys()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        if key in self._order:
            self._order.remove(key)
        self._order.append(key)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        dict.__delitem__(self, key)
        self._order.remove(key)

    def order(self):
        return self._order[:]

    def ordered_items(self):
        return [(key,self[key]) for key in self._order]


od = ordered_dict()
od["hello"] = "world"
od["goodbye"] = "cruel world"
print od.order()            # prints ['hello', 'goodbye']

del od["hello"]
od["monty"] = "python"
print od.order()            # prints ['goodbye', 'monty']

od["hello"] = "kitty"
print od.order()            # prints ['goodbye', 'monty', 'hello']

print od.ordered_items()
# prints [('goodbye','cruel world'), ('monty','python'), ('hello','kitty')]
```

Comment: Is order_dict( ('key_a','value_a'), ('key_b','value_b') ) ordered correctly? Looks like _order would be set to self.keys() in __init__, which is ordered in the hash-ordering, not the order it was entered? Just curious.

Comment: You're correct, which is why I said, "the order of values passed to the constructor is undefined but will come before values passed later".  It would be possible to order those properly, but I wasn't sure whether that was a desired behavior, since arguably such objects are inserted simultaneously.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this with the base dict class -- it's ordered by hash.  You could build your own dictionary that is really a list of key,value pairs or somesuch, which would be ordered.

Comment: Your dictionary implementation can instead use a standard dictionary and a list - the dictionary stores the key->value associations, and the list stores keys in the order they are inserted.

Answer (score 5):

Or, just make the key a tuple with time.now() as the first field in the tuple.

Then you can retrieve the keys with dictname.keys(), sort, and voila!

Gerry

Comment: This makes it impossible to look up entries in the dict without knowing exactly when you inserted them. It's no better than a list of key-value pairs.

Answer (score 3):

I've used StableDict before with good success.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/StableDict/0.2

Answer (score 1):

Or use any of the implementations for the [PEP-372](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/) described [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/#reference-implementation), like the [odict module](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/odict.html) from the [pythonutils](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/pythonutils.html).

I successfully used the pocoo.org implementation, it is as easy as replacing your

```
my_dict={}
my_dict["foo"]="bar"
```

with

```
my_dict=odict.odict()
my_dict["foo"]="bar"
```

and require just [this file](http://dev.pocoo.org/hg/sandbox/raw-file/tip/odict.py)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible unless you store the keys in a separate list for referencing later.

Answer (score -1):

if you don't need the dict functionality, and only need to return tuples in the order you've inserted them, wouldn't a queue work better?

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is insert the values with a key representing the order inputted, and then call `sorted()` on the items.

```
>>> obj = {}
>>> obj[1] = 'Bob'
>>> obj[2] = 'Sally'
>>> obj[3] = 'Joe'
>>> for k, v in sorted(obj.items()):
...     print v
... 
Bob
Sally
Joe
>>>
```

Comment: If we didn't already need the key for other purposes, we would use a list. This does nothing a list doesn't do better.

Comment: @user2357112, however, this expresses another method of doing **what the OP asked**. The OP did not ask how to print items in the order they were inserted, the OP said how to print items **in a `dict`**. Big difference.

Comment: You've changed the format of the dict to the point of making it unuseful for the original purpose, though. If the dict was originally associating, say, names to phone numbers, you've gained a consistent iteration order, but you have no idea what Bob's phone number is.