# Equivalent for LinkedHashMap in Python

Tags: python

[LinkedHashMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is the Java implementation of a Hashtable like data structure (dict in Python) with predictable iteration order. That means that during a traversal over all keys, they are ordered by insertion. This is done by an additional linked list maintaining the insertion order.

Is there an equivalent to that in Python?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of Python 3.7, `dict` objects maintain their insertion order by default.

If you're on Python 2.7 or Python >=3.1 you can use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in the standard library.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848/how-do-you-retrieve-items-from-a-dictionary-in-the-order-that-theyre-inserted/61031#61031) to the question [How do you retrieve items from a dictionary in the order that they’re inserted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848/how-do-you-retrieve-items-from-a-dictionary-in-the-order-that-theyre-inserted) contains an implementation of an ordered dict, in case you're not using Python 3.x and don't want to give yourself a dependency on the third-party [ordereddict module](http://www.xs4all.nl/~anthon/Python/ordereddict/).

Answer (score 12):

Although you can do the same thing by maintaining a list to keep track of insertion order, [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) and [Python >=3.1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) have an OrderedDict class in the collections module.

Before 2.7, you can subclass `dict` [following this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/).

Comment: The OrderedDict is coming in Python 3.1, but is not yet in 3.0, according to the documentation you linked.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether this is what you are asking for:

```
>>> dic = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
>>> for k, v in dic.iteritems():
...     print k, v
```

you can order the dic in the order of the insertion using [ordereddict](http://www.xs4all.nl/~anthon/Python/ordereddict/) module.

```
d = ordereddict(dic, relax=True)
```

Comment: I don't think ``dict.iteritems`` provides an ordering based on the order of insertion...

Comment: Correct! You have to use ordereddict module for that.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the validated comment;

As of Python 3.7, `dict` preserves insertion order.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777540/11953327) shows this with details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so; you'd have to use a dict plus a list.  But you could pretty easily wrap that in a class, and define `keys`, `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, etc. to make it work the way you want.