# LinkedHashSet alternative in python

Tags: java, python-3.x, linkedhashmap, linkedhashset

```
Iterator i1=h1.iterator();
while(i1.hasNext()){
int p=(int)(i1.next());
}
```

Please explain this code in python programming language term, here h1 is **linkedhashset**
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this answer [Equivalent for LinkedHashSet for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653887/equivalent-for-linkedhashmap-in-python)

Comment: @AndresSacco can you explain this above code bcz i am new to java

Comment: This looks like homework. Voting to close as it shows no attempt from author to solve it.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I think you are not getting him. He already mentioned that he is new to java and want the explanation of the above code in python . So how he will show you that he attempt to understand the above code or not ? also the LinkedHashSet is difficult part for a beginner so there is nothing wrong in asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different ways to iterate a "LinkedHashSet", for example using: "forEach" or "iterate".

An iterator is an object that can be used to iterate all the elements in a collection. The Iterator has two important methods (hasNext, next).

I put an explanation about each line of your code

```
Iterator i1 = h1.iterator(); //obtain an iterator of the collection
while(i1.hasNext()) { // Continue iterating because has a next element 
  int p=(int)(i1.next()); //return the next element and parse it to "int"
}
```

Also with an Iterator you can add or remove elements.

**Additional resources:**

[Java Iterator - Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-iterator-in-java/)

[Java official Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)