# Dictionary in python with order I set at start

Tags: python, collections, dictionary

I'm making dictionary:

```
d = {"server":"mpilgrim", "database":"master"}
d['mynewkey'] = 'mynewvalue'
```

But when I display it I saw that this dict is reversed.

```
print(d)

{'mynewkey': 'mynewvalue', 'database': 'master', 'server': 'mpilgrim'}
```

How to reverse it back?

Or if it is true that dictionary is not sortable what I must to use to have collection where the order of that informations matters?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Dictionary are unordered (the order is deterministic, but depends on a handful of factors you don't even think of and shouldn't care about - hash of the keys, order of insertion, collisions, etc). In Python 2.7+, use `collections.OrderedDict`. If you must use an older version, there are various implementations google can point you to.

Comment: The easiest implementation being a list of tuples, especiall if speed isn't an issue.

Comment: Yes, that's easiest, but it performs *horribly*. Especially when it's used with algorithms that assume "real" (i.e. `O(1)` read/write/`in`) dicts

Answer (score 20):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
d["server"] = "mpilgrim"
d["database"] = "master"
d['mynewkey'] = 'mynewvalue'

print(d)

OrderedDict([('server', 'mpilgrim'), ('database', 'master'), ('mynewkey', 'mynewvalue')])
```

Comment: No, it's not ok, because, at start "server":"mpilgrim" was first. Now is second

Comment: Right, I fixed the key insertion once I noticed. For `OrderedDicts`, you need to add keys using the [ ] operator (`__setitem__`). Insertion order is preserved.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using python 3.6 dictionaries are now ordered by insertion order

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/

Otherwise (as other people have said) I would recommend collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Be careful, this is an implementation detail of CPython in 3.6 and may not hold in other implementations. In 3.7 it is guaranteed by the language spec.

Comment: As @SorenBjornstad says: In Python 3.8.x dicts are not ordered by insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionnary is not quite reverted. It is sorted partly according to the hash of you keys. You can't change this order (not without using a custom dictionary). In python 2.7 or later you can use an ordered dictionary (`collections.OrderedDict`).

In earlier version you can use the following [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/107747-ordered-dictionary/).

Also have a look at this question : [What is the best ordered dict implementation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/719744/64633)