# Dictionary keys are not coming in serial

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you retrieve items from a dictionary in the order that they’re inserted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848/how-do-you-retrieve-items-from-a-dictionary-in-the-order-that-theyre-inserted)

I have an issue with django view and template

After getting details related to a meeting like

```
        for meeting in get_meetings:
           if meeting.venue_id ==None:
                 mee_data = {} 
                 mee_data['id'] = meeting.id
                 getdate = meeting.meeting_datetime
                 mee_data['date'] = getdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                 mee_data['end_time'] = meeting.end_time
                 mee_data['meeting_duration'] = meeting.meeting_duration 
                 mee_data['start_time'] = meeting.start_time 
                 mee_data['meetingID'] = meeting.meetingID
                 mee_data['id'] = meeting.id
                 mee_data['start_time'] = meeting.start_time 

                 mee_data['name'] = meeting.name

                 getall.append(mee_data)
```

Where getall is a list i have declared above

Now after appending the dictionary data.

I am expecting the result in my template is like

```
[{"id": "REG_431103567", "date": "", "end_time": "", "meeting_duration": "", "start_time": "2012-10-29", "meetingID": 192dnjd, "name": "TEsts"},...]
```

basically the order of keys but unfortunately the result is coming like .

```
[{"meetingID": "REG_431103567", "start_time": "", "meeting_duration": "", "end_time": "", "date": "2012-10-29", "id": 192, "name": "TEsts"},...]
```

Please suggest me what should i do here so that i could get the keys and their corresponding values in proper way .

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2030935/647772

Comment: Dictionaries in python are unordered. Use http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Have you considered handling it in the template by showing each attribute separately? I mean, the dict formatting isn't going to look good in webpage output anyway...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to get the data in the order it was inserted.

Dictionaries don't maintain the order but an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which is a sub-class 0f `dict` can maintain the order.

**Example:**

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict()
>>> d["key1"]="foo"
>>> d["key2"]="bar"
>>> d
OrderedDict([('key1', 'foo'), ('key2', 'bar')])
```

Note: `OrderedDict` was introduced in python 2.7, so will not work in previous versions.

Comment: @user1667633 Note that `OrderedDict` was introduced in python 2.7 only, so will not work in previous versions.

Comment: Note that there are implementations available for previous versions of Python. See the answer to the question that is marked as duplicate.

Comment: @moooeeeep Interestingly even the question is before the time of python 2.7 release. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OrderedDict` instead of normal `dict`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

for meeting in get_meetings:
           if meeting.venue_id ==None:
                 mee_data = OrderedDict()
                 ...
```