# How to implement an ordered, default dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to combine `OrderedDict()` and `defaultdict()` from `collections` in one object, which shall be an ordered, default `dict`.
Is this possible?

Comment: Even though you've already accepted a solution, you might want to check-out the somewhat simpler `OrderedDefaultdict` class I wrote for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126348/how-do-i-rewrite-this-function-to-implement-ordereddict/4127426#4127426).

Comment: [I wonder why you can't just create a class that inherits `OrderedDict ` and `defaultdict`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27712226/1484957a0)

Comment: @drs see my answer below, which does exactly that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35968897/1644561

Comment: I understand that from Python 3.7 onwards the insertion order is maintained for anything that inherits from the regular `dict` - that includes the `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The following (using a modified version of [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/523034-emulate-collectionsdefaultdict/)) works for me:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, Callable

class DefaultOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    # Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6190500/562769
    def __init__(self, default_factory=None, *a, **kw):
        if (default_factory is not None and
           not isinstance(default_factory, Callable)):
            raise TypeError('first argument must be callable')
        OrderedDict.__init__(self, *a, **kw)
        self.default_factory = default_factory

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return OrderedDict.__getitem__(self, key)
        except KeyError:
            return self.__missing__(key)

    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        self[key] = value = self.default_factory()
        return value

    def __reduce__(self):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            args = tuple()
        else:
            args = self.default_factory,
        return type(self), args, None, None, self.items()

    def copy(self):
        return self.__copy__()

    def __copy__(self):
        return type(self)(self.default_factory, self)

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        import copy
        return type(self)(self.default_factory,
                          copy.deepcopy(self.items()))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'OrderedDefaultDict(%s, %s)' % (self.default_factory,
                                               OrderedDict.__repr__(self))
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, which was similar in thought process but designed on the fly (and hence needed to implement various other functions).

Comment: @Neil G: You probably should just use the built-in `callable()` function to test `default_factory`. Using `isinstance(default_factory, Callable)` actually requires it to have more than just callability -- see the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=callable#collections.Callable) -- which is all that's is needed here.

Comment: @martineau: You're right.  I believe `callable` was removed in Python 3.1 and then reinstated in Python 3.2, and I hadn't upgraded yet when I made this edit.  Feel free to make the change.

Comment: @Neil G: Actually `callable()` was first removed in Python 3.0 and then brought back in Python 3.2. Anyway, consider changing it yourself if you wish (I like my own answer better anyway ;-). I generally tend to shy away from just hopping in and changing someone else's answer, preferring instead to only make comments as I've done here.

Comment: @zeekay: I think you might need to change `self.items()` into `iter(self.items())` inside `__reduce__`. Otherwise, `PicklingError` exception is raised complaining that fifth argument of the `__reduce__` must be an iterator.

Comment: @max: Instead of changing it to `iter(self.items())` it would be simpler to use `self.iteritems()`. Also, the type of error you get from not doing either depends on whether you're using the `pickle` or `cPickle` module. With `pickle`, the error message is `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'` for the same reason (because the list object passed isn't an iterator). FWIW, the first element of the returned tuple could also be changed from `type(self)` to a simpler `self.__class__`.

Comment: When I `copy.deepcopy()` an instance of this object, I get a maximum recursion depth exception. In `DefaultOrderedDict.__deepcopy__`, my quick fix is to change the argument `copy.deepcopy(self.items())` to `copy.deepcopy(tuple(self.items())`.

Answer (score 49):

Here is another possibility, inspired by [Raymond Hettinger's super() Considered Super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), tested on Python 2.7.X and 3.4.X:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict

class OrderedDefaultDict(OrderedDict, defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, default_factory=None, *args, **kwargs):
        #in python3 you can omit the args to super
        super(OrderedDefaultDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.default_factory = default_factory
```

If you check out the class's MRO (aka, `help(OrderedDefaultDict)`), you'll see this:

```
class OrderedDefaultDict(collections.OrderedDict, collections.defaultdict)
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      OrderedDefaultDict
 |      collections.OrderedDict
 |      collections.defaultdict
 |      __builtin__.dict
 |      __builtin__.object
```

meaning that when an instance of `OrderedDefaultDict` is initialized, it defers to the `OrderedDict`'s init, but this one in turn will call the `defaultdict`'s methods before calling `__builtin__.dict`, which is precisely what we want.

Comment: This answer, despite its elegance and simplicity, doesn't work in Python3. Since both OrderedDict and defaultdict are implemented in C, you get a TypeError, "multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict."  That's because the C classes have differing, and incompatible, ideas of how to lay out the internal data structures. The accepted answer above works well in Python3, with a few tiny changes (super().__getitem__(... instead of OrderedDict.__getitem_(... ). I'm using Python3.5.

Comment: Interesting, this works correctly in Python 3.4.3

Is there any way to see where the TypeError is coming from in the C code?

Comment: so beautiful. a shame it doesn't work in Python 3.

Comment: As of Python 3.6 this will be unnecessary, as all `dicts`, and therefore all `defaultdicts`, will be ordered. I am ok with it not working on 3.5 ;)

Comment: Though `dicts` in CPython 3.6 preserve order, it is an implementation detail not to be relied upon, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39980548/91243. Use `OrderedDict` if that is what you want.

Comment: It's an implementation detail, but if it’s there to support an official feature of the language now in the spec: ordered `**kwargs`. The quote mentioned in @amjoconn’s comment deserves to be more complete, [read release notes on 3.6 in full](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation). Note how frustratingly dissembling the docs are: per _letter_ this “shouldn’t be relied upon”, then in parens it “may” be codified in the future, and if you ask me the _spirit_ of it is “it’s an awesome feature and it’s already in PyPy, just let’s wait before adding this to the spec”.

Comment: From videos, the consensus from PyCon seems to be moving toward making the ordering standard: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66P5FMkWoVU. Nothing official yet.

Comment: It's now offical Guido approved it.

Comment: @Fruch still, dicts don't support "move_to_end"

Comment: @ErikAronesty what's move to end ? and how it's related to the OP question?

Answer (score 40):

If you want a simple solution that doesn't require a class, you can just use [`OrderedDict.setdefault(key, default=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) or [`OrderedDict.get(key, default=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). If you only get / set from a few places, say in a loop, you can easily just setdefault.

```
totals = collections.OrderedDict()

for i, x in some_generator():
    totals[i] = totals.get(i, 0) + x
```

It is even easier for lists with `setdefault`:

```
agglomerate = collections.OrderedDict()

for i, x in some_generator():
    agglomerate.setdefault(i, []).append(x)
```

But if you use it more than a few times, it is probably better to set up a class, like in the other answers.

Comment: This really is the cleanest answer!

Answer (score 29):

Here's another solution to think about if your use case is simple like mine and you don't necessarily want to add the complexity of a `DefaultOrderedDict` class implementation to your code.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
items = [(key, None) for key in keys]
od = OrderedDict(items)
```

*(`None` is my desired default value.)*

Note that this solution won't work if one of your requirements is to dynamically insert new keys with the default value.  A tradeoff of simplicity.

**Update 3/13/17** - I learned of a convenience function for this use case.  Same as above but you can omit the line `items = ...` and just:

```
od = OrderedDict.fromkeys(keys)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('a', None), ('b', None), ('c', None)])
```

And if your keys are single characters, you can just pass one string:

```
OrderedDict.fromkeys('abc')
```

This has the same output as the two examples above.

You can also pass a default value as the second arg to `OrderedDict.fromkeys(...)`.

Comment: Thank you! `od = OrderedDict((k, None) for k in iterable)`

Comment: This assumes your keys are predefined in some iterable though, so downstream objects would need to be aware that adding a new key requires an initial value. To be more precise, you couldn't assume an initial value for something like:

    `>>> od = OrderedDefaultDict(int)
    >>> od['foo'] += 100
    OrderedDefaultDict([('foo', 100)])`

This case would be correctly handled by a solution like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35968897/1644561).

Comment: @avyfain That's correct.  For my use case, it was just the initial data so future inserts of keys not previously defined wasn't relevant.  I'll add a note to make the assumption explicit.

Answer (score 12):

Another simple approach would be to use dictionary `get` method

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> d['key'] = d.get('key', 0) + 1
>>> d['key'] = d.get('key', 0) + 1
>>> d
OrderedDict([('key', 2)])
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

A simpler version of @zeekay 's answer is:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class OrderedDefaultListDict(OrderedDict): #name according to default
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = value = [] #change to whatever default you want
        return value
```

Comment: You can even override `__init__` to catch the "default_factory" of the new items.

Answer (score 7):

A simple and elegant solution building on @NickBread. 
Has a slightly different API to set the factory, but good defaults are always nice to have.

```
class OrderedDefaultDict(OrderedDict):
    factory = list

    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = value = self.factory()
        return value
```

Answer (score 0):

I created slightly fixed and more simplified version of the accepted answer, actual for python 3.7.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from copy import copy, deepcopy
import pickle
from typing import Any, Callable


class DefaultOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(
            self,
            default_factory: Callable[[], Any],
            *args,
            **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.default_factory = default_factory

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            return self.__missing__(key)

    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = value = self.default_factory()
        return value

    def __reduce__(self):
        return type(self), (self.default_factory, ), None, None, iter(self.items())

    def copy(self):
        return self.__copy__()

    def __copy__(self):
        return type(self)(self.default_factory, self)

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        return type(self)(self.default_factory, deepcopy(tuple(self.items()), memo))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.default_factory}, {OrderedDict(self).__repr__()})'
```

And, that may be even more important, provided some tests.

```
a = DefaultOrderedDict(list)

# testing default
assert a['key'] == []
a['key'].append(1)
assert a['key'] == [1, ]

# testing repr
assert repr(a) == "DefaultOrderedDict(<class 'list'>, OrderedDict([('key', [1])]))"

# testing copy
b = a.copy()
assert b['key'] is a['key']
c = copy(a)
assert c['key'] is a['key']
d = deepcopy(a)
assert d['key'] is not a['key']
assert d['key'] == a['key']

# testing pickle
saved = pickle.dumps(a)
restored = pickle.loads(saved)
assert restored is not a
assert restored == a

# testing order
a['second_key'] = [2, ]
a['key'] = [3, ]
assert list(a.items()) == [('key', [3, ]), ('second_key', [2, ])]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is ordered by insertion order on Python **3.7**+ (and CPython 3.6+).

Answer (score -2):

Inspired by other answers on this thread, you can use something like,

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class OrderedDefaultDict(OrderedDict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = OrderedDefaultDict()
        self[key] = value
        return value
```

I would like to know if there're any downsides of initializing another object of the same class in the **missing** method.

Comment: This is an ordered dict where the default value is always another ordered dict. Not really what the question was about.

Answer (score -3):

i tested the default dict and discovered it's also sorted!
maybe it was just a coincidence but anyway you can use the sorted function:

```
sorted(s.items())
```

i think it's simpler

Comment: `sorted` is likely different than the insertion order of OrderedDict.