# OrderedDict KeyError

Tags: python, collections, dictionary, comparison

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(dict)

d["i"]["a"] = "111"
d["i"]["b"] = "222"

print d

od = collections.OrderedDict()

od["i"]["a"] = "111"
od["i"]["b"] = "222"

print od
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'i': {'a': '111', 'b': '222'}})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_main.py", line 51, in run_toplevel
  File "/Users/adam/Desktop/collections.py", line 12, in <module>
    od["i"]["a"] = "111"
KeyError: 'i'
```

Why the key error with OrderedDict and what I can do about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `OrderedDict` is not also a `defaultdict`. You'd have to do something like this:

```
import collections
od = collections.OrderedDict()
od["i"] = collections.OrderedDict()
od["i"]["a"] = "111"
od["i"]["b"] = "222"
print od
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('i', OrderedDict([('a', '111'), ('b', '222')]))])
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190331/can-i-do-an-ordered-default-dict-in-python) for a potential ordered defaultdict implementation.

Comment: With this I lose the insertion order which is why I am using OrderedDict

Comment: @AdamSilver: then use an `OrderedDict` for the inner one, too. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thats the main advantage of defaultdict especially, it will capture the Keyerror and call the function passed as the argument to defaultdict.  But OrderedDict is for different purpose.

If a new dataStrcture combines both functionality would be beneficial.  Also, using userDict() it must be possible to implement such a functionality.

You can refer my article on Python Collections

https://techietweak.wordpress.com/2015/11/11/python-collections/

Hope this helps.