# Check that item exists in a dictionary of OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I can't see to get this working, having key error so was wondering if anyone could let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> people = OrderedDict()
>>> people['Depark'] = 'Jaipor'
>>> people['James'] = 'Walubi'
>>> 
>>> work = OrderedDict()
>>> work['Train drive'] = 'Big_train'
>>> work['Teacher'] = 'Maths_teacher'
>>>
>>>
>>> def props():
...    d = dict()
...    d['people'] = people
...    d['work'] = work
...    return d

>>> test = props()
>>> if test['people']['Mandeep']:
...     print 'We have Mandeep'
... else:
...    print 'No one by that name'
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Mandeep'
```

I was expecting it to print `'No one by that name'` as we don't have Mandeep as a key.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283578/ordereddict-keyerror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test['people']['Mandeep']` is evaluated **before** the `if` condition is processed. Unsurprisingly, it raises `KeyError`. One Pythonic solution is to use a `try` / `except` construct:

```
try:
    test['people']['Mandeep']
    print('We have Mandeep')
except KeyError:
    print('No one by that name')
```

If you *want* to use an `if` / `else` clause, you can check if the key exists in your sub-dictionary:

```
if 'Mandeep' in test['people']:
    print('We have Mandeep')
else:
    print('No one by that name')
```

Comment: Thanks, will try the two suggestion and see let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `.get(key, [default_value])` to check if the item exists in OrderedDict. Details can be found in [Python documentation on get method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

```
from collections import OrderedDict

people = OrderedDict()
people['Depark'] = 'Jaipor'
people['James'] = 'Walubi'

work = OrderedDict()
work['Train drive'] = 'Big_train'
work['Teacher'] = 'Maths_teacher'


def props():
    d = dict()
    d['people'] = people
    d['work'] = work
    return d


test = props()

if test['people'].get('Mandeep'):
    print('We have Mandeep')
else:
    print('No one by that name')
```

**Output:**

```
No one by that name
```

**Explanation:**

Here, we are searching for the name `Mandeep` in our OrderedDict `people` and if it is not found, it is set to `None`. Thus if the key is not found the `else` block is executed.

**References:**

- [Python documentation on get method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)