# How can i use default ordered dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am following this example
[Can I do an ordered, default dict in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190331/can-i-do-an-ordered-default-dict-in-python)

But when i use this

```
if mydict['item']`
```

then i am getting the key error. It should not give me that error.

Shouldn't it suppose to be empty even if key don't exist

Comment: Do you create `mydict` with `default_factory` argument?

Comment: It works for me using that recipe.  Can you show a simple reproducible example?

Comment: no , how should i do that

Comment: @gatto -- Ooo ... Good call.  If you create it with no `default_factory` then it implicitly gets set to `None` which would cause the KeyError.

Comment: Alternatively just use the `dict.get` and `dict.setdefault` methods alongside a normal `OrderedDict`

Comment: @user2294401 -- It'd just be something like:  `mydict = DefaultOrderedDict(func)` where `func` is a function which takes 0 arguments and returns whatever "default" value you want the defaultdict to have.

Comment: FWIW -- I never realized you could create a `defaultdict` without setting the `default_factory`.  Very interesting.

Comment: I am using like this `d = DefaultOrderedDict(list)`

Comment: Show us the whole code, except for the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have default values in your dict, you have to set default_factory, which must be a callable.

Example usage:

```
d = DefaultOrderedDict(lambda: None)
assert d['item'] is None

# as with normal dict, you can init it with another dict
d = {'key': 'value'}
d = DefaultOrderedDict(list, d)
assert d['item'] == []
assert d['key'] == 'value'
```

Comment: I am using like this d = DefaultOrderedDict(list)

Comment: With `list` also works for me.

Comment: is there any way that if i already have normal dict and i convert that to DefaultDict.  I think i am coverting thata to json and ethen from json coverting back to dict by json.loads() , so think i ahve lost that during conversion