# How can I create an ordered dictionary from json in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am posting the form and then grabbing the json to form the dict .

```
myd = \
{'a': {'b': 'c1', 'd': 'f1'},
 'b': {'bb': 'c2', 'dd': 'f2'},
 'c': {'bbb': 'c3', 'ddd': 'f3'}
}
```

Now I am using josn.loads to convert that into python dict

I am doing this

```
        headers = DefaultOrderedDict(list, json.loads(request.POST.get('myd')))
```

[Can I do an ordered, default dict in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190331/can-i-do-an-ordered-default-dict-in-python)

after doing that my order of the dict gets changed like this

```
  myd = \
    {'a': {'b': 'c1', 'd': 'f1'},
     'c': {'bbb': 'c3', 'ddd': 'f3'},
     'b': {'bb': 'c2', 'dd': 'f2'},
}
```

How can I maintain the order?

Comment: You probably just need a `sorted` call somewhere ... where do you get `DefaultOrderedDict` from?!

Comment: . I don't want to sort by any key but i just want to have the same order as original That came from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190331/can-i-do-an-ordered-default-dict-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should do:

```
json.loads(request.POST.get('myd'), object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
```

You can see some documentation about the object_pairs_hook keyword in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of the python dictionary object is to provide you with O(1) access to key value pairs. As a result the dictionary may choose to arrange it in different order for better performance needs. Having said that you can always do something similar to :

```
for key in sorted(myd.iterkeys()):
    print "%s: %s" % (key, myd[key])
```