# Ordering with default dict append

Tags: python, json, string, ipython

I have a Python code, see below, which takes a JSON file in the structure:

```
{
    "name":"Winking Entertainment",
    "imports":"Translink Capital"
  },
  {
    "name":"Wochacha",
    "imports":"Sequoia Capital"
  },
  {
    "name":"Wuhan Kindstar Diagnostics",
    "imports":"Baird Venture Partners"
  },
```

And aggregates repeat values in "imports" and turns the matching strings into a single array for that entry. (see snippet below)

```
   import json

from collections import defaultdict

def map_names_to_imports(raw_data):
  name_to_imports = defaultdict(list)
  for row in raw_data:
     name_to_imports[row['imports']].append(row['name'])
  return name_to_imports

def reformat(name_to_imports):
  output = []
  for name, imports in name_to_imports.items():
    new_dict = {
      'name': name,
      'imports': list(set(imports))
    }
    output.append(new_dict)
  return output

def run(raw_data):
  name_to_imports = map_names_to_imports(raw_data)
  output = reformat(name_to_imports)
  with open('clean-data2.json','wb') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(output))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  raw_data = json.load(open('bricinvestors.json'))
  run(raw_data)
```

The issue I am having is my Json file is not coming out the right way.

For some reason, name and imports are getting reversed. So my output looks like:

```
  {"imports": ["SinoHub"], "name": "Iroquois Capital"}, {"imports": ["Qunar.com", "Lashou.com"], "name": "Tenaya Capital"}
```

In fact, I want to keep the {"name": "string", "imports": "string"} format -- and not the other way around.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use a [DefaultOrderedDict](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6190500/190597).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final version, which is based in large part on @unutbu's answer.

```
import json
import collections
OrderedDict = collections.OrderedDict

def map_names_to_imports(raw_data):
    name_to_imports = OrderedDict()
    for row in raw_data:
        name_to_imports.setdefault(row['imports'], []).append(row['name'])
    return name_to_imports

def reformat(name_to_imports):
    the_output = []
    for name, imports in name_to_imports.items():
        new_dict = OrderedDict([('name', name),
                                ('imports', list(set(imports)))])
        the_output.append(new_dict)
    return the_output

def run(raw_data):
    name_to_imports = map_names_to_imports(raw_data)
    the_output = reformat(name_to_imports)
    with open('data/clean-data2.json',  'w+', encoding='utf8') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(the_output))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  raw_data = json.load(open('data/bricsinvestorsfirst.json'), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
  run(raw_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 2.7+, you could use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)  as your input to json.loads(), instead of the standard Python dict. The standard library dict class doesn't guarantee the ordering of keys.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [dano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822440/190597), you could use the [OrderedDict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method instead of using a defaultdict:

```
import json
import collections
OrderedDict = collections.OrderedDict

def map_names_to_imports(raw_data):
    name_to_imports = OrderedDict()
    for row in raw_data:
        name_to_imports.setdefault(row['imports'], []).append(row['name'])
    return name_to_imports


def reformat(name_to_imports):
    output = []
    for name, imports in name_to_imports.items():
        new_dict = OrderedDict([('name', name),
                                ('imports', list(set(imports)))])
        output.append(new_dict)
    return output


def run(raw_data):
    name_to_imports = map_names_to_imports(raw_data)
    output = reformat(name_to_imports)
    with open('clean-data2.json', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(output))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    raw_data = json.load(open('bricinvestors.json'),
                         object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    run(raw_data)
```

Comment: I've been playing with this but without much luck. For one thing, I don't think the double "collections.collections" is correct. This also still results in the same list order as my original code..

Comment: @SamP.: My mistake. OrderedDicts need to be used in a number of places. `json.load` also needs `object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict` to preserve the order of the keys.