# Default ordered dictionaries in Python 2.7.x

Tags: python

Besides the answers from ~3 years ago in this question:

[Can I do an ordered, default dict in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190331/can-i-do-an-ordered-default-dict-in-python)

Have any implementations been adopted into recent versions of Python?

If not, why not?

Answer (score 4):

No, for **default** options, you will only have the built-in dictionary which is *not* ordered. If you do want an ordered dictionary, you will *have* to import the module **`OrderedDict`**.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
```

You do, however, have the option of creating a list of tuples which *will* maintain its order.

Instead of:

`a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3}`

you would do it as:

`a = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I'm not on 2.7, so cannot test, but this should reimplement a `defaultdict` subclassed from `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class DefaultOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, default):
        self.default = default
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        try:
            return OrderedDict.__getitem__(self, x)
        except KeyError:
            self[x] = self.default()
            return self[x]
```

Comment: Please let me know in the comments if I've missed anything, as I can't test it