# Python: Writing an empty dictionary with strings thats ordered

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Please realize I'm trying not looking for a default ordered dictionary like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190331/can-i-do-an-ordered-default-dict-in-python). Something similar.

If I call an OrderedDict from the collections module I can do -

```
 from collections import OrderedDict
 my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
```

Then I can just set items like this which calls on the setitem function, where I assume the magic happens -

```
 my_ordered_dict[key1] = value1
 my_ordered_dict[key2] = value2
 my_ordered_dict[key3] = value3
```

And get a perfectly OrderedDict -

```
>my_ordered_dict
 {key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3...}
```

However, when I try to just initilize my key value pairing like this:

```
my_ordered_dict = {key1 : value1,
                   key2 : value2,
                   key3 : value3...}
```

The dictionary loses order.

I can hack my way around this by instead of initializing a list of tuples:

```
default = [ (key1, value1), (key2, value2), (key3, value3)]

for pair in default:
   my_ordered_dict[pair[0]] = pair[1]
```

But it seems like i'm missing something. Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict(( (key1, value1), (key2, value2), (key3, value3) ))
```

The above works because the argument we are using is tuple and a tuple is ordered.

Again because a tuple is ordered, this will also work :

```
my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
my_ordered_dict.update(( (key1, value1), (key2, value2), (key3, value3) ))
```

By contrast, this will *not* work:

```
my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict({key1:value1, key2:value2,})
```

The argument to `OrderedDict` above is an unordered dictionary.  All order was lost when it was created.

Interestingly, though, order can be reimposed on an unordered dictionary as these examples from the [documention for the collections module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) show:

```
>>> # dictionary sorted by key
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])

>>> # dictionary sorted by value
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)])

>>> # dictionary sorted by length of the key string
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[0])))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('apple', 4), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you write:

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

It will be evaluated as a normal dictionary and immediately lose its order. In your example, you are overwriting `my_ordered_dict` with a normal dictionary.

Instead, you could use a list of tuples:

```
OrderedDict([('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2'), ('key3', 'value3')])
```

Comment: @levi It doesn't maintain the order of the keys, since you are passing them through a normal dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the OrderedDict like this to create an OrderedDict:

```
>>> dct = OrderedDict(((key1, value1), (key2, value2), (key3, value3)))
>>> type(dct)
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
```

that is, a dict created like this produces a normal dict and not an OrderedDict:

```
>>> dct = {key1: value1, key2 : value2, key3 : value3}
>>> type(dct)
<type 'dict'>
```

Check the python docs for some [good OrderedDict examples](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes).

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
my_ordered_dict = {key1 : value1,
                   key2 : value2,
                   key3 : value3...}
```

That is a ordinary(unsorted) dict, you need to do this:

```
my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict(((key1, value1), (key2, value2), (key3, value3)))
```