# Why can't I create a default, ordered dict by inheriting OrderedDict and defaultdict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, defaultdict, ordereddictionary

My first attempt to combine the features of two dictionaries in the `collections` module was to create a class that inherits them:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict

class DefaultOrderedDict(defaultdict, OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, default_factory=None, *a, **kw):
        super().__init__(default_factory, *a, **kw)
```

However, I cannot assign an item to this dictionary:

```
d = DefaultOrderedDict(lambda: 0)
d['a'] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/collections/__init__.py", line 64, in __setitem__
    self.__map[key] = link = Link()
AttributeError: 'DefaultOrderedDict' object has no attribute '_OrderedDict__map'
```

Indeed, [this question about how to create a similar object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6190331/1484957) has answers that achieve it by extending the `OrderedDict` class and manually re-implementing the additional methods provided `defaultdict`. Using multiple inheritance would be cleaner. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: As an aside, you can use `defaultdict(int)` instead of `defaultdict(lambda: 0)`.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that the [`init` method of `defaultdict`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/483746c32296/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#l1670) instead of calling `__init__` of the next class in MRO calls init of `PyDict_Type` hence some of the attributes like `__map` that are set in [OrderedDict's `__init__`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l41) are never initialized, hence the error.

```
>>> DefaultOrderedDict.mro()
[<class '__main__.DefaultOrderedDict'>,
 <class 'collections.defaultdict'>,
 <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>,
 <class 'dict'>, <class 'object'>]
```

And `defaultdict` don't have their own `__setitem__` method:

```
>>> defaultdict.__setitem__
<slot wrapper '__setitem__' of 'dict' objects>
>>> dict.__setitem__
<slot wrapper '__setitem__' of 'dict' objects>
>>> OrderedDict.__setitem__
<unbound method OrderedDict.__setitem__>
```

So, when you called `d['a']` = 1, in search of `__setitem__` Python reached OrdereredDict's `__setitem__` and their the access of uninitialized `__map` attribute raised the error:

---

A fix will be to call `__init__` on both `defaultdict` and `OrderedDict` explicitly:

```
class DefaultOrderedDict(defaultdict, OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, default_factory=None, *a, **kw):
        for cls in DefaultOrderedDict.mro()[1:-2]:
            cls.__init__(self, *a, **kw)
```

Comment: Why can't you just swap the order of the base classes: `class OrderedDefaultDict(OrderedDict, defaultdict):`, and then have your `__init__(self, default_factory=None, *args, **kwargs)` contain two lines: `super(OrderedDefaultDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` and `self.default_dict = default_dict`?

Comment: I just tried Sam's suggestion and it worked. (Well, after I changed default_dict to default_factory!)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are coming from a Java background, but multiple inheritance doesn't do what you'd expect it does in Python. Calling super from the **init** of the defaultOrderedDict calls the super() as the **init** of defaultdict and never the **init** of OrderedDict. The **map attribute is first defined in the __init** function of OrderedDict. The implementation is the following (from source):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    '''Initialize an ordered dictionary.  The signature is the same as
    regular dictionaries, but keyword arguments are not recommended because
    their insertion order is arbitrary.

    '''
    if len(args) > 1:
        raise TypeError('expected at most 1 arguments, got %d' % len(args))
    try:
        self.__root
    except AttributeError:
        self.__root = root = []                     # sentinel node
        root[:] = [root, root, None]
        self.__map = {}
    self.__update(*args, **kwds)
```

Note that this doesn't have to do with the attribute being private. A minimal example with multiple inheritance can illustrate this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo=2

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar=1

class FooBar(Foo,Bar):
     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

fb = FooBar()

fb.foo
>>2 
fb.bar
>>AttributeError: 'FooBar' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

So, the constructor of Bar was never called. Pythons method resolution order goes from left to right until it finds a class with the function name it seeks (in this case **init**) and then ignores all other classes on the right (in this case Bar)