# How to create ordered dictionary of dictionary of list in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

With the following class

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict
class NestedOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __missing__(self,k):
        val = self[k] = NestedOrderedDict()
        return self[k]
```

I tried to make **ordered dictionary of dictionary of list**

```
orddodol = NestedOrderedDict()
orddodol["foo"]["a"].append(1)
orddodol["foo"]["b"].append(1)
orddodol["foo"]["b"].append(12)
orddodol["bar"]["a"].append(2)
orddodol["bar"]["a"].append(3)
```

But it failed giving

```
AttributeError: 'NestedOrderedDict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 4):

You have to initialize the second level dictionary values as lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict
class NestedOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __missing__(self,k):
        val = self[k] = NestedOrderedDict()
        return self[k]

orddodol = NestedOrderedDict()
orddodol["foo"]["a"] = []           # these
orddodol["foo"]["b"] = []           # three
orddodol["bar"]["a"] = []           # lines
orddodol["foo"]["a"].append(1)
orddodol["foo"]["b"].append(1)
orddodol["foo"]["b"].append(12)
orddodol["bar"]["a"].append(2)
orddodol["bar"]["a"].append(3)
```

Answer (score 4):

You almost did it right :) If you want to create ordered dictionary of **dictionary of list**, then you'd better use `defaultdict(list)` for that purpose:

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict
class NestedOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __missing__(self, k):
   >>>> self[k] = defaultdict(list)
        return self[k]

orddodol = NestedOrderedDict()
orddodol["foo"]["a"].append(1)
orddodol["foo"]["b"].append(1)
orddodol["foo"]["b"].append(12)
orddodol["bar"]["a"].append(2)
orddodol["bar"]["a"].append(3)
```

Comment: Bah just beat me to it :)

Comment: This completely changes what `NestedOrderedDict` does -- you can no longer do something like `orddodol["aa"]["bb"]["cc"] = []` for example.

Comment: yes, but question was about ordered dictionary of dictionary of list (just two layers)

Comment: Given that the code has keys like "foo" and "bar", I considered it an example and didn't try to assume anything about it only working for two layers.  He asked about the "right way" to do it, which, while this works for his example, it clearly is not.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict
class NestedOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __missing__(self,k):
        val = self[k] = NestedOrderedDict()
        return self[k]

orddodol = NestedOrderedDict()
orddodol["foo"]["a"] = []
orddodol["foo"]["b"] = []
orddodol["bar"]["a"] = []
orddodol["foo"]["a"].append(1)
orddodol["foo"]["b"].append(1)
orddodol["foo"]["b"].append(12)
orddodol["bar"]["a"].append(2)
orddodol["bar"]["a"].append(3)
```

or you can implement a defaultdict with ordered like this post [Can I do an ordered, default dict in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190331/can-i-do-an-ordered-default-dict-in-python)

```
from collections import OrderedDict, Callable
class DefaultOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190500/562769
    def __init__(self, default_factory=None, *a, **kw):
        if (default_factory is not None and
           not isinstance(default_factory, Callable)):
            raise TypeError('first argument must be callable')
        OrderedDict.__init__(self, *a, **kw)
        self.default_factory = default_factory

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return OrderedDict.__getitem__(self, key)
        except KeyError:
            return self.__missing__(key)

    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        self[key] = value = self.default_factory()
        return value

    def __reduce__(self):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            args = tuple()
        else:
            args = self.default_factory,
        return type(self), args, None, None, self.items()

    def copy(self):
        return self.__copy__()

    def __copy__(self):
        return type(self)(self.default_factory, self)

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        import copy
        return type(self)(self.default_factory,
                          copy.deepcopy(self.items()))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'OrderedDefaultDict(%s, %s)' % (self.default_factory,
                                               OrderedDict.__repr__(self))
```