# Access objects in ordered default dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I am using an order default dict from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190331/can-i-do-an-ordered-default-dict-in-python) . The problem is that i don't know how to access the objects.

I am expecting that something like this should work

```
{% for zone in data %}
    {% for reservation in zone %}
        {{reservation}} # 1 | 2| 3
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Data to help the debug

```
{{data}}

OrderedDefaultDict(<type 'list'>, DefaultOrderedDict([('1', [<app.backoffice.models.Reservation object at 0x7f91c2c5ee10>, <app.backoffice.models.Reservation object at 0x7f91c2c732d0>, <app.backoffice.models.Reservation object at 0x7f91c2c73510>]), ('2', [<app.backoffice.models.Reservation object at 0x7f91c2c73790>, <app.backoffice.models.Reservation object at 0x7f91c32f9c50>]), ('3', [<app.backoffice.models.Reservation object at 0x7f91c2c733d0>, <app.backoffice.models.Reservation object at 0x7f91c2c73490>])]))
```

---

```
{% for zone in data %}
   {{zone}} # 1 | 2 | 3
   {{zone[0]}} # 1 | 2 | 3
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Presumably just like you'd access the data in a plain `dict`.

Comment: What template language is this, Django templates, Jinja2, something else entirely?

Comment: @MartijnPieters jinja and flask

Comment: And you expect something to work; what happened when you tried? Was there a specific error?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just want to iterate the objects for each key. there is no error, my example just print the key.

Comment: @user2990084: right, because your keys are strings with just one character. `zone` is set to `'1'`, looping over that string gives you the character `'1'` (the only character in the string). Indexing to `zone[0]` gives you that same character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you loop over a dictionary (even a subclass) you get *keys*; you'd have to translate that key into a value first if you want to loop over nested objects:

```html
{% for zone in data %}
    {% for reservation in data[zone] %}
        {{reservation}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Since you don't display the `zone` key, you may as well loop over the dictionary values (using `dict.itervalues()` to avoid creating a redundant list object):

```html
{% for reservations in data.itervalues() %}
    {% for reservation in reservations %}
        {{reservation}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

or use `dict.iteritems()` to get both the key and the value:

```html
{% for zone, reservations in data.iteritems() %}
    {{zone}}: 
    {% for reservation in reservations %}
        {{reservation}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In your own attempts, `zone` was only ever set to each key, which in your case are single-character strings (`'1'`, `'2'` and `'3'`). Looping over a single-character string or indexing that string with `zone[0]` will only result in that one character to be shown.