# Python: Create set by removing duplicates in text processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, set, duplicates

Let's say a text file with two columns like below

```
A "
A "
A l
A "
C r
C "
C l
D a
D "
D "
D "
D d
R "
R "
R "
R " 
S "
S "
S o
D g
D "
D "
D "
D j
A "
A "
A z
```

I would like retrieve the information like below

```
list1= {A:l}, {C:r,l}, {D:a,d}, {S:o}
final_list= {A:l}, {C:r,l}, {D:a,d}, R{}, {S:o}
```

I understand that , I have to access the text file `line.strip().split()`

and after that I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Cannot understand the logic. Why `{D: a}` was skipped?. What have you done so far?

Comment: Sorry, I missed it.  Updated the question .  Will update the script which I tried.

Comment: since you've got two dictionaries that you want, `list1` and `final_list`, perhaps working on both at the same time?

Comment: @dwanderson : yes,  list1 will be used compared with some other dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
list1 = collections.defaultdict(set)
final_list = collections.defaultdict(set)
for line in filetext: ## assuming youve opened it, read it in
    key, value = line.strip().split()
    final_list[key].add(value)
    if value != '"':
        list1[key].add(value)
```

This is slightly different in that `final_list` will have the empty string as an element; this doesn't match what you said, so let's alter it a little:

```
import collections
list1 = collections.defaultdict(set)
final_list = {}
for line in filetext: ## assuming youve opened it, read it in
    key, value = line.strip().split()
    if key not in final_list:
        final_list[key] = set()
    if value != '"':
        list1[key].add(value)
final_list.update(list1)
```

This should give you what you want - existence with empty-sets for things like `R`.

Comment: In the second answer the second if loops  shows indentation error.

Comment: Which line has an indentation error? I intentionally put `final_list.update` after all the lines because you only need to do it once, at the end of the file. If it's something else, just let me know and I'll fix it

Comment: `import collections
list1 = collections.defaultdict(set)
final_list = {}
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
 for line in f: ## assuming youve opened it, read it in
     key, values = line.strip().split()
     if key not in final_list:
         final_list[key] = set()
         if values:
          list1[key].add(values)
final_list.update(list1)
print(list1)
print(final_list)`

Comment: final_list = `{'A': {'"'}, 'C': {'r'}, 'D': {'a'}, 'R': {'"'}, 'S': {'"'}}`,

Comment: final_list = `{'A': {'"'}, 'C': {'r'}, 'D': {'a'}, 'R': {'"'}, 'S': {'"'}}`    & list1 = `defaultdict(set, {'A': {'"'}, 'C': {'r'}, 'D': {'a'}, 'R': {'"'}, 'S': {'"'}})`

Comment: Oh, instead of `if value:` do `if value != '"':`; I'll fix that

Comment: But your `final_list` is actually a dictionary :) Don't do that.

Comment: Oh yeah, better variable names, for sure. Just sticking with OP so it's easier for them to follow, but I agree with you

Comment: @alex Belyaev Oh yes, I forgot that. Shall I make the Final_list as List after ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

In case if order of dicts in `final_list` **DOESN'T** matter:

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open('/home/bwh1te/projects/stackanswers/wordcount/data.txt') as f:
    occurencies = defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split()
        # invoke of occurencies[key] in this condition
        # cause autocreating of this key in dict
        if value not in occurencies[key] and value.isalpha(): 
            occurencies[key].append(value)

# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'C': ['r', 'l'], 'D': ['a', 'd'], 'S': ['o'], 'A': ['l'], 'R': []})
# Use it like a simple dictionary

# In case if it must be a list, not a dict:
final_list = [{key: value} for key, value in occurencies.items()]
# [{'C': ['r', 'l']}, {'D': ['a', 'd']}, {'S': ['o']}, {'A': ['l']}, {'R': []}]
```

In case if order of dicts in `final_list` **DOES** matter:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open(file_path) as f:
    occurencies = OrderedDict()
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split()
        # Create each key anyway
        if key not in occurencies:
            occurencies[key] = []        
        if value.isalpha():
            if value not in occurencies[key]:
                occurencies[key].append(value)

# OrderedDict([('A', ['l']), ('C', ['r', 'l']), ('D', ['a', 'd']), ('R', []), ('S', ['o'])])

# In case if it must be a list, not a dict
final_list = [{key: value} for key, value in occurencies.items()]
# [{'A': ['l']}, {'C': ['r', 'l']}, {'D': ['a', 'd']}, {'R': []}, {'S': ['o']}]

list1 = [{key: value} for key, value in occurencies.items() if value]
# [{'A': ['l']}, {'C': ['r', 'l']}, {'D': ['a', 'd']}, {'S': ['o']}]
```

Or you can implement hybrid of OrderedDict and defauldict like that: [Can I do an ordered, default dict in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190331/can-i-do-an-ordered-default-dict-in-python) :)

Comment: The order matters here.I will be comparing the  `for all in list1`  I will compare `final_list [-1]` & `final_list [1]`.

Comment: @Rangooski Okay... It should preserve order of file records or sort alphabetically?

Comment: it should be in order of file records. Not alphabetically.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.  I will try learn the this concept of Ordered Dict.

Comment: final_list dint give the expected result. It gives  `final_list =  [{'A': ['l']}, {'C': ['r', 'l']}, {'D': ['a', 'd']}, {'S': ['o']}]`

Comment: @Rangooski emm... what is the difference? There should be an 'empty' dict for 'R'?

Comment: But the `list1` is not here .  `final_list = [{'A': ['l']}, {'C': ['r', 'l']}, {'D': ['a', 'd']}, {'R': []}, {'S': ['o']}]`     `occurencies = OrderedDict([('A', ['l']), ('C', ['r', 'l']), ('D', ['a', 'd']), ('R', []), ('S', ['o'])])`

Comment: Oh, it wasn't clear... I thought that `list1` is some temporary list to create a `final_list` :) And what do you expect to see in `list1`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103293/discussion-between-rangooski-and-alex-belyaev).