# Complex grouping list items

Tags: python, django, group-by

I need to display notifications in Facebook format using python. But finding it difficult to group the items. Following is the list from query

[image: sample list]

The notification must be displayed as follows

- John changed Name, Code, Description of Product Shirt
- John changed Name of Product Hat
- John changed Variant Code of Hat
- Mike changed Name of Product Trouser, Hat
- Kiet changed Name of Variant XXL Shirt

Is there any possibility of doing this using python group by? and order by date?

Comment: What is the python data structure that the items are in? A 2-dimensional list? A dictionary? It is hard to answer the question when you have only posted an image

Comment: @JeffMandell items are from SQLAlchemy result, could be converted to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following approach using `groupby`, which seems to work for your existing data but might need further thought for other edge cases:

```
from itertools import groupby
from datetime import datetime

results = [
    ["User", "Type", "Changed", "Product Name", "Date"],
    ["John", "Product", "Name", "Shirt", "1-Jan-17"],
    ["John", "Product", "Code", "Shirt", "1-Jan-17"],
    ["John", "Product", "Description", "Shirt", "1-Jan-17"],
    ["John", "Product", "Name", "Hat", "1-Jan-17"],
    ["John", "Variant", "Code", "XXL Shirt", "1-Jan-17"],
    ["Mike", "Product", "Name", "Trouser", "2-Jan-17"],
    ["Mike", "Product", "Name", "Tie", "3-Jan-17"],
    ["Kiet", "Variant", "Name", "XXL Shirt", "4-Jan-17"]]

sorted_results = sorted(results[1:], key=lambda x: (datetime.strptime(x[4], '%d-%b-%y'), x[0]))

for k1, g1 in groupby(sorted_results, lambda x: x[0]):
    grouped_by_name = list(g1)
    v1, v2 = [], []

    for k2, g2 in groupby(grouped_by_name, lambda x: (x[1], x[3])):  # type, name
        v1.append(list(g2))

    for k2, g2 in groupby(grouped_by_name, lambda x: (x[1], x[2])):  # type, changed
        v2.append(list(g2))

    if len(v1) < len(v2):
        for entry in v1:
            entries = [changed for user, ptype, changed, pname, date in entry]
            print("{} changed {} of {} {}".format(entry[0][0], ', '.join(entries), entry[0][1], entry[0][3]))
    else:
        for entry in v2:
            entries = [pname for user, ptype, changed, pname, date in entry]
            print("{} changed {} of {} {}".format(entry[0][0], entry[0][2], entry[0][1], ', '.join(entries)))
```

This would display the following output:

```
John changed Name, Code, Description of Product Shirt
John changed Name of Product Hat
John changed Code of Variant XXL Shirt
Mike changed Name of Product Trouser, Tie
Kiet changed Name of Variant XXL Shirt
```

Comment: It says "'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'" at sorted_results = ... Any idea?

Comment: Strange, which version of Python are you on?

Comment: I am using version 3.4.4

Comment: I can use time.strptime, let me check

Comment: Martin, last help please, I cannot get "user" in print(), could you please correct that? Thanks!

Comment: I have just updated it and tested it on Python 3.5, still not sure why you have problems with datetime though?  Did you use `import datetime` instead of `from datetime import datetime`? If the former, just change to `datetime.datetime.strptime()`

Comment: Returned the date in date format from the query, so problem solved. Thanks you, the code worked.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to reduce the rows to be rows that have the same user and product name values. I am using a dictionary (default dict) to map the user/product name to a list of their changed elements.

```
from collections import defaultdict
# Assuming your datastructure looks like:
rows = [['jeff', 'product', 'name', 'shirt'], ['jeff', 'product', 'code', 'shirt'], ['mike', 'product', 'name', 'trouser']]
user_index = 0
changed_index = 2
product_name_index = 3

delimeter = '&&&'
changed_items = defaultdict(list)
for row in rows:
    key = '%s%s%s' % (row[user_index], delimeter, row[product_name_index])
    changed_items[key].append(row[changed_index])

for key, changed in changed_items.iteritems():
    user, product = key.split(delimeter)
    print('%s changed %s of %s' % (user, ', '.join(changed), product))
```

If you want it sorted by order, you will have to use a default AND ordered dictionary. You can use this implementation of said data structure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190500/3741585