# os.walk find a directory which is not even present

Tags: python, os.walk

I need to extract some values out of a file, i wrote the following code.

```
import os
import sys
rootdir='/home/nsingh/ansible-environments/aws'
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
  for j in subdirs:
    print j
    mypath=rootdir+'/'+j+'/inventory/group_vars/all'
    #print mypath
    fo=open(mypath,'r')
    f=fo.readlines()
    for line in f:
            if ('isv_alias' in line or 'LMID' in line or 'products' in line):
                         path='/home/nsingh/krikCSV_fun.csv'
                         if('isv_alias' in line):
                            line=line.strip('isv_alias=')
                            line= line.strip('"')
                         elif('LMID'  in line):
                            line=line.strip('LMID=')
                         else:
                            line=line.strip('products=')

                         fi= open(path,'a+')
                         fi.write(line)
                         fi.close()
    fo.close()
```

the os.walk method somehow finds a hidden directory as well which is not actually present

```
loadgen
crapcity
rmstest2
suricatatest
.git
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testme.py", line 9, in <module>
    fo=open(mypath,'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/nsingh/ansible-environments/aws/.git/inventory/group_vars/all'
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
: "suricatatest"^M
: suricatatest
: rms_ems_hosted
: 26
: rmstest2
: rms_scl
: 80
: suricatatest
: rms_ems_hosted
: 26
: "suricatatest"^M
: suricatatest
: rms_ems_hosted
: 26
```

I need the output as & also remove the semicolon:

```
suricatatest rms_ems_hosted 26
```

Comment: The files you are interested in are all named ```'all'``` with no extension?

Comment: yes , it has no extension

Comment: Please add a few lines of one of the files as an example.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that `/.git` doesn't exist?

Try this:

```
import os

rootdir = '/home/nsingh/ansible-environments/aws'
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for j in subdirs:
        print(j)
        my_path = rootdir + '/' + j + '/inventory/group_vars/all'
        if os.path.isfile(my_path):
            with open(my_path, 'r') as fo:
                for line in fo.readlines():
                    if 'isv_alias' in line or 'LMID' in line or 'products' in line:
                        path = '/home/nsingh/krikCSV_fun.csv'
                        if 'isv_alias' in line:
                            line = line.strip('isv_alias=')
                            line = line.strip('"')
                        elif 'LMID' in line:
                            line = line.strip('LMID=')
                        else:
                            line = line.strip('products=')

                        with open(path, 'a+') as fi:
                            fi.write(line.lstrip(": "))
```

Comment: i have checked that there is no hidden dir wih ls-la

Comment: Fair enough. That's weird then.

Comment: this is wrong.. it goes inside that directory, it is creating the .git

Comment: loadgen
crapcity
rmstest2
suricatatest
.git
inventory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testme.py", line 10, in <module>
    fo=open(mypath,'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/nsingh/ansible-environments/aws/inventory/inventory/group_vars/all'
nsingh@syd01-devops-ansible02:~/kriko_test$ cd /home/nsingh/ansible-environments/aws/

Answer (score 0):

You should use [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) to make the file paths.  os.walk will visit all the directories in the tree under the top directory - you are only interested in directories that end with `'inventory/group_vars'`, so check for that and take action.  If you want to write the values as a *group*, you need to collect them in something.

```
import os, os.path, collections
rootdir = '/home/nsingh/ansible-environments/aws'
sub_folder = 'inventory/group_vars'
out_path = '/home/nsingh/krikCSV_fun.csv'
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdir):
    if dirpath.endswith(sub_folder):
        data = collections.defaultdict(list)
        with open(os.join(dirpath, 'all')) as f, open(out_path, 'a+') as out:
            for line in f:
                if 'isv_alias' in line:
                    line = line.strip('isv_alias=')
                    line = line.strip('"')
                    data['isv_alias'].append(line)
                elif 'LMID'  in line:
                    line = line.strip('LMID=')
                    data['LMID'].append(line)
                elif 'products' in line:
                    line = line.strip('products=')
                    data['products'].append(line)
            for a, b, c in zip(*data.values()):
                out.write('{},{},{}\n'format(a, b, c))
```

I used a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to store multiple items of interest from a single file.  If there is only one `'isv_alias', 'LMID', 'products'` *group* in each file then you could just as easily store the information in a list or namedtuple.

---

You didn't provide an example of the file(s) so it's not clear what the line structure is.  If it looks like this:

```
isv_alias="foo"
LMID=bar
products=26
```

It can be simplified to

```
keys = {'isv_alias', 'LMID', 'products'}
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdir):
    if dirpath.endswith(sub_folder):
        data = collections.defaultdict(list)
        with open(os.join(dirpath, 'all')) as f, open(out_path, 'a+') as out:
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()
                key, value = line.split('=')
                if key in keys:
                    value = value.strip('"')
                    data[key].append(value)
            for a, b, c in zip(*data.values()):
                out.write('{},{},{}\n'format(a, b, c))
```

---

As long as you are accumulating the information in `data`, you can just open the output file once

```
data = collections.defaultdict(list)
keys = {'isv_alias', 'LMID', 'products'}
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdir):
    if dirpath.endswith(sub_folder):
        with open(os.join(dirpath, 'all')) as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()
                key, value = line.split('=')
                if key in keys:
                    value = value.strip('"')
                    data[key].append(value)

with open(out_path, 'a+') as out:
    for a, b, c in zip(*data.values()):
        out.write('{},{},{}\n'format(a, b, c))
```

---

If using Python 3.6 or an [ordered defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35968897/2823755) then the solution above assumes the order of appearance of each *key* in the file is the order you want them written out.

If the file structure isn't *ordered* or the dictionary used isn't ordered, write to the file like this:

```
            for a, b, c in zip(data['isv_alias'], data['LMID'], data['products']):
                out.write('{},{},{}\n'format(a, b, c))
```