# Finding common intersection between various values of a columns in a dataframe where values are array/list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a dataframe whose first 5 rows looks like this.

```
 userID       CategoryID          sectorID
agunii2035  [16, 17, 3, 12, 1]  [2, 33, 29, 18, 23]
agunii3007  [2, 4, 6, 3, 16]    [4, 15, 29, 10, 18]
agunii2006  [8, 16, 2, 5, 12]   [38, 18, 7, 36, 33]
agunii2003  [6, 4, 2, 5, 17]    [37, 12, 3, 32, 34]
agunii3000  [12, 11, 7, 3, 1]   [38, 1, 13, 25, 3]
```

Now for any `userID` (let say "userID" = 'agunii2035') , I want to get the "userID"s whose "`CategoryID`" or "`SectorID`" have at least one common intersection value (For example, since agunni2035 and aguni3007 have at least one common "`CategoryID`" i.e '16' or have one common "`sectorID`" i.e. '29', we will consider the "`userID` " 'agunii3007')

The output can be a dataframe that looks like this

```
   userID         user_with_common_cat/sectorID
agunii2035      {aguni3007, agunni2006, agunii2003, agunii300}
aguni3007       {agunni2035,agunni2006,agunii2003}

and so on
```

or this can also be

```
   userID         user_with_common_cat/sectorID
agunii2035      [aguni3007, agunni2006, agunii2003, agunii300]
aguni3007       [agunni2035,agunni2006,agunii2003}

and so on
```

Any help on this please?

**Edit**

What I have done so far:

```
userID= 'agunii2035'

common_users = []

for user in uniqueUsers:
    common = list(set(df_interest.loc[df_interest['userID'] == 'agashi2035', 'categoryID'].iloc[0]).intersection(df_interest.loc[df_interest['userID'] == user, 'categoryID'].iloc[0]))
                  
    #intersect = len(common) > 0
                  
    if (len(common) > 0):
            common_users.append(user)
```

I want to do this for sectors as well and make the intersection for either sector or category and append to the `common_user` list if length of any intersection is 1.

Also, I want to do this for all the users.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have just done a static one for a single user.


`userID= 'agunii2035'

common_users = []

for user in uniqueUsers:
    common = list(set(df_interest.loc[df_interest['userID'] == 'agashi2035', 'categoryID'].iloc[0]).intersection(df_interest.loc[df_interest['userID'] == user, 'categoryID'].iloc[0]))
                  
    #intersect = len(common) > 0
                  
    if (len(common) > 0):
            common_users.append(user)`

I want to add the sectors part as well and do this for all users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually don't really like to manipulate `dataframe` where a "cell" contains a list and not s single element (`float`, `str`, etc.).

In the following I will manipulate a python `dict` instead of a `dataframe`.

#### Data

You can transform a pandas `dataframe` into `dict` with the `to_dict` method [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

Here are the data in dictionnary:

```py
d = {
        "agunii2035": {
            "category_id": [16, 17, 3, 12, 1],
            "sector_id": [2, 33, 29, 18, 23],
        },
        "agunii3007": {
            "category_id": [2, 4, 6, 3, 16],
            "sector_id": [4, 15, 29, 10, 18],
        },
        "agunii2006": {
            "category_id": [8, 16, 2, 5, 12],
            "sector_id": [38, 18, 7, 36, 33],
        },
        "agunii2003": {
            "category_id": [6, 4, 2, 5, 17],
            "sector_id": [37, 12, 3, 32, 34],
        },
        "agunii3000": {
            "category_id": [12, 11, 7, 3, 1],
            "sector_id": [38, 1, 13, 25, 3],
        },
    }
```

### Solution 1: Iterate over the dictionary with for loops

Here we can have two for loops to check all elements. The only thing to know is how to intersect two `list` in python with `set`.

```py
results = {}
for user_a, category_sector_a in d.items():
    results[user_a] = []
    for user_b, category_sector_b in d.items():
        if user_a != user_b:
            # we use "set" to have common elements between the two lists
            intersection_category = set(category_sector_a["category_id"]) & set(
                category_sector_a["category_id"]
            )
            intersection_sector = set(category_sector_a["sector_id"]) & set(
                category_sector_a["sector_id"]
            )
            if (len(intersection_category)) > 0 or (len(intersection_category) > 0):
                results[user_a].append(user_b)
```

### Solution 2: itertools

Here, we use `itertools` to generate all combinations of `keys` in the original data. It will allow us to avoid the two `for loops`.

```py
import itertools

results = {}
for user_a, user_b in itertools.combinations(d.keys(), 2):
    # we use "set" to have common elements between the two lists
    intersection_category = set(d[user_a]["category_id"]) & set(
        d[user_b]["category_id"]
    )
    intersection_sector = set(d[user_a]["sector_id"]) & set(d[user_b]["sector_id"])
    if (len(intersection_category)) > 0 or (len(intersection_category) > 0):
        if user_a in results:
            results[user_a].append(user_b)
        else:
            results[user_a] = [user_b]
```

It is almost the same thing as previously. Except, at the end we have to create the `key` in the `results` dictionary if the `key` doesn't exist.

### Solution 3: itertools and list comprehension

Here, we also use the itertools but in a `list` comprehension. We use `list` comprehension to output only users pair respecting the condition (the `if` part).

```py
import operator
import itertools

results = [
    (user_a, user_b)
    for user_a, user_b in itertools.combinations(d.keys(), 2)
    if (len(set(d[user_a]["category_id"]) & set(d[user_b]["category_id"]))) > 0
    or (len(set(d[user_a]["sector_id"]) & set(d[user_b]["sector_id"])) > 0)
]
results = {
    k: list(list(zip(*g))[1])
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(results, operator.itemgetter(0))
}
```

Note at the end the part where we need to `groupy` because the output of the `list` comprehension is a list of users tuple (pairs). The solution to `groupy` list of tuples in python comes from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45476509/group-list-of-tuples-efficiently/45476721) on SO.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did the solution 1.