# Merge tuples with the same key

Tags: python, tuples

How to merge a tuple with the same key

```
list_1 = [("AAA", [123]), ("AAA", [456]), ("AAW", [147]), ("AAW", [124])]
```

and turn them into

```
list_2 = [("AAA", [123, 456]), ("AAW", [147, 124])]
```

Comment: Related: [Python: merge lists of tuples based on its values](//stackoverflow.com/q/18446476)

Comment: all those years and not a single exact dupe... I had a good look. Maybe it's somewhere, well...

Answer (score 17):

The most performant approach is to use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) dictionary to store data as an expanding list, then convert back to tuple/list if needed:

```
import collections

list_1 = [("AAA", [123]), ("AAA", [456]), ("AAW", [147]), ("AAW", [124])]

c = collections.defaultdict(list)
for a,b in list_1:
    c[a].extend(b)  # add to existing list or create a new one

list_2 = list(c.items())
```

result:

```
[('AAW', [147, 124]), ('AAA', [123, 456])]
```

note that the converted data is probably better left as dictionary. Converting to list again loses the "key" feature of the dictionary.

On the other hand, if you want to retain the order of the "keys" of the original list of tuples, unless you're using python 3.6/3.7, you'd have to create a list with the original "keys" (ordered, unique), then rebuild the list from the dictionary. Or use an `OrderedDict` but then you cannot use `defaultdict` (or use a [recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190331/can-i-do-an-ordered-default-dict-in-python))

Comment: Note that this answer would not necessarily retain the order of the original list, if that is a consideration.

Comment: true, unless you're using python 3.7. To retain the original order you'd have to create a list with the original "keys" (ordered, unique), then rebuild the list from the dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a dict to keep track of the indices of each key to keep the time complexity O(n):

```
list_1 = [("AAA", [123]), ("AAA", [456]), ("AAW", [147]), ("AAW", [124])]
list_2 = []
i = {}
for k, s in list_1:
    if k not in i:
        list_2.append((k, s))
        i[k] = len(i)
    else:
        list_2[i[k]][1].extend(s)
```

`list_2` would become:

```
[('AAA', [123, 456]), ('AAW', [147, 124])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary and loop through the list. If the item present in dictionary append the value to already existing list else assign the value to key.

```
dict_1 = {}
for item in list_1:
    if item[0] in dict_1:
        dict_1[item[0]].append(item[1][0])
    else:
        dict_1[item[0]] = item[1]
list_2 = list(dict_1.items())
```

Comment: It does the merge but doesn't retain the original order in the list.  The result I got is: `[('AAW', [147, 124]), ('AAA', [123, 456])]` - AAA should have been the first element as in the original list.

Comment: If the order is important then we can use OrderedDict from the collections
from collections import OrderedDict
dict_1 = OrderedDict()

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to other answers, you can use a dictionary to associate each key with a list of values. This is implemented in the function `merge_by_keys` in the code snippet below.

```
import pprint

list_1 = [("AAA", [123]), ("AAA", [456]), ("AAW", [147]), ("AAW", [124])]

def merge_by_key(ts):

    d = {}
    for t in ts:
        key = t[0]
        values = t[1]
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = values[:]
        else:
            d[key].extend(values)

    return d.items()



result = merge_by_key(list_1)

pprint.pprint(result)
```

Comment: @codeforester Just a slip up. I had list_2 in my code in order to print it after the computed result, to check that my solution is correct. Removed it right now actually.