# I want to add tuple value to tuple if that tuple[0:2] is repeated as shown below:

Tags: python, list, tuples

Here i have list

```
some_list = [('A','B','IP1','N1'),('A','B','IP3','N3'),('B','C','IP2','N2'),('B','C','IP3','N3'),('D','F','IP4','N4')]
```

for suppose `'A','B'` is in `('A','B','IP1','N1'),('A','B','IP3','N3')`
then we need to combine both tuple and make as one tuple and replace `('A','B','IP1','N1'),('A','B','IP3','N3')` with `('A','B','IP1','N1','IP3','N3')` in `some_list`

Result:

```
some_list = [('A','B','IP1','N1','IP3','N3'), ('B','C','IP2','N2','IP3','N3'), ]
```

should come but make sure instead of 'A', 'B','C',.. what ever it'll not be same for everytime

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Just install `ordered-set`, check https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/. After that you can try `some_list = [tuple(set(some_list[i] + some_list[i + 1])) for i in range(0, len(some_list) - 1, 2)]` to get the result. I have written this in the answer where you can see the differences with `set()` and `OrderedSet()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically you need to create a tuple key for your 2 values, and create a default dictionary with that.

Extend the rest of the list for each key, and transform back the key/value couple to list of lists by adding the key (as list) to the value

like this:

```
import collections

some_list = [('A','B','IP1','N1'),('A','B','IP3','N3'),('B','C','IP2','N2'),('B','C','IP3','N3'),('D','F','IP4','N4')]

c = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k1,k2,*b in some_list:   # extended iterable unpacking allows this
    c[(k1,k2)].extend(b)  # add to existing list or create a new one

result = [a+tuple(b) for a,b in c.items()]
```

result:

```
>>> result
[('D', 'F', 'IP4', 'N4'),
 ('B', 'C', 'IP2', 'N2', 'IP3', 'N3'),
 ('A', 'B', 'IP1', 'N1', 'IP3', 'N3')]
```

The `for k1,k2,*b in some_list` part allows to put the 2 first values in separate `k1` and `k2` variables, and the "rest" in a `b` list. This feature isn't available in python 2. Python 2 users can replace the loop by a more basic:

```
for a in some_list:
    c[tuple(a[:2])].extend(a[2:])  # add to existing list or create a new one
```

(this problem is similar to that one: [Merge tuples with the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52454582/merge-tuples-with-the-same-key) for the core part, but the pre/post processing makes it different)

Comment: for k1,k2,*b in some_list:   # extended iterable unpacking allows this
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you're using python 2. Let me add a compatible solution

Comment: changed final conversion

Comment: Can you please check this question also?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363521/need-to-avoid-nested-for-loop-as-it-is-repeating-70007000-times-for-7000-rows?noredirect=1#comment93603732_53363521

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the tuples by the first two items, then combine the rest of the tuple at the end with flattening:

```
from itertools import groupby
from itertools import chain
from pprint import pprint


some_list = [
    ("A", "B", "IP1", "N1"),
    ("A", "B", "IP3", "N3"),
    ("B", "C", "IP2", "N2"),
    ("B", "C", "IP3", "N3"),
    ("D", "F", "IP4", "N4"),
]

# key -> first two, rest -> everything after first two
key, rest = lambda x: x[:2], lambda x: x[2:]

pprint(
    [
        list(chain.from_iterable((k, *tuple(map(rest, g)))))
        for k, g in groupby(sorted(some_list, key=key), key=key)
    ]
)
```

Which gives the following:

```
[['A', 'B', 'IP1', 'N1', 'IP3', 'N3'],
 ['B', 'C', 'IP2', 'N2', 'IP3', 'N3'],
 ['D', 'F', 'IP4', 'N4']]
```

The above uses [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the grouped tuple of tuples. You also need to sort the list of tuples by the first two items, in order to group them with `itertools.groupby()`. This is because it groups by consecutive keys in an iterable, which you can only achieve by sorting.

Additionally, If your list of tuples are always of length 4 and the key is always the first two items, you can also use [`operater.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for `key` and `rest`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
key, rest = itemgetter(0, 1), itemgetter(2, 3)
```

Which looks up the first two values *(0, 1)* and last two values *(2, 3)*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below code.

```
>>> def get_combined_items(tup1, tup2):
...     l = list(tup1)
...     for item in tup2:
...         if item not in l:
...             l.append(item)
...     return l
...
>>>
>>> if len(some_list) % 2 == 0: # even number of items
...     some_list = [tuple(get_combined_items(some_list[i], some_list[i + 1])) for i in range(0, len(some_list) - 1, 2)]
... else:
...     last_item = some_list[-1] # save last item
...     some_list = [tuple(get_combined_items(some_list[i], some_list[i + 1])) for i in range(0, len(some_list) - 1, 2)]
...     some_list = some_list + [last_item]
...
>>> some_list
[('A', 'B', 'IP1', 'N1', 'IP3', 'N3'), ('B', 'C', 'IP2', 'N2', 'IP3', 'N3'), ('D', 'F', 'IP4', 'N4')]
>>>
```

And if you want to try 3rd party package then install `ordered-set` using `pip install ordered-set`.

> » pip install ordered-set

You can check https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/.

> **Note:** This is just to keep the elements in order after passing the combined tuple to `set()`.

```
>>> from ordered_set import OrderedSet
>>>
>>> some_list = [('A','B','IP1','N1'),('A','B','IP3','N3'),('B','C','IP2','N2'),('B','C','IP3','N3'),('D','F','IP4','N4')]
>>>
>>> if len(some_list) % 2 == 0: # even number of items
...     some_list = [tuple(OrderedSet(some_list[i] + some_list[i + 1])) for i in range(0, len(some_list) - 1, 2)]
... else:
...     last_item = some_list[-1] # save last item
...     some_list = [tuple(OrderedSet(some_list[i] + some_list[i + 1])) for i in range(0, len(some_list) - 1, 2)]
...     some_list = some_list + [last_item]
...
>>>
>>> some_list
[('A', 'B', 'IP1', 'N1', 'IP3', 'N3'), ('B', 'C', 'IP2', 'N2', 'IP3', 'N3'), ('D', 'F', 'IP4', 'N4')]
>>>
```

Comment: In Input there is also ('D','F','IP4','N4') which is missing in your result

Comment: As I understood, you want to loop through 2 items in each iteration. So, what should be the final answer in this case. Just paste, I will fix and update my answer. I saw, it is also missing in your question, the `result` value.

Comment: some_list_input = [('A','B','IP1','N1'),('A','B','IP3','N3'),('B','C','IP2','N2'),('B','C','IP3','N3'),('D','F','IP4','N4')] and my output list should be [('A', 'B', 'IP1', 'N1', 'IP3', 'N3'), ('B', 'C', 'IP2', 'N2', 'IP3', 'N3'), ('D','F','IP4','N4')] and index shouldn't change and i shouldn't install any outside packages only i need to use inbuilt packages

Comment: Okay, got, thanks for reply & now I have updated my answer, you can check.

Comment: Sorry as I have mentioned that I shouldn't install any outside packages only python inbuilt packages need to be used

Comment: @smily, I've updated my answer, you can check. Thanks for replying with new update.

Comment: Thanks it is working but i don't want to use for loops much because i have huge data, but its ok i have done it

Comment: Can you please check this question also?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363521/need-to-avoid-nested-for-loop-as-it-is-repeating-70007000-times-for-7000-rows?noredirect=1#comment93603732_53363521

Comment: The link does not exist.