# Sort defaultdict by key?

Tags: python

I am grouping a list of objects together by their timestamp:

```
object_list = [
{
    timestamp: datetime.strptime("01/01/2014", "%d/%m/%y"),
},
{
    timestamp: datetime.strptime("12/05/2014", "%d/%m/%y"),
},
{
    timestamp: datetime.strptime("03/01/2014", "%d/%m/%y"),
},
{
    timestamp: datetime.strptime("01/01/2014", "%d/%m/%y"),
}]

date_grouped_objects = defaultdict(list)

for obj in object_list:
    date_grouped_objects[obj.timestamp].append(obj)
```

Which gives me exactly what I want, a list of objects grouped together by their timestamp attribute.

**Question: I now want to sort date_grouped_objects by the keys (the timestamps), but it isn't clear how you can use sorted to achieve this? So the most group with the most recent date would be last**

So what I'm after is:

```
[
    ["01/01/2014"] = [...],
    ["03/01/2014"] = [...],
    ["12/05/2014"] = [...],
]
```

Where the keys are actually date objects, not strings.

Comment: So what have you tried, and what is wrong with it? Which of those are you having a problem with? Sorting? Making the date objects from the strings? What is your output data structure supposed to be - it is a cross between a list and some assignments and ???

Comment: Edited my question. I am just trying to figure out how sort the resulting date_grouped_objects by it's keys

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that runs and demonstrates the problem. For example, your data doesn't match the `strptime` template, and `timestamp` isn't defined. And, again, what is the output you expect - what have written there **is not** a valid Python structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the`OrderedDefaultdict`class from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4127426/355230) of mine to do something like the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
from ordereddefaultdict import OrderedDefaultdict

object_list = [{'timestamp': datetime.strptime("01/01/2014", "%d/%m/%Y")},
               {'timestamp': datetime.strptime("12/05/2014", "%d/%m/%Y")},
               {'timestamp': datetime.strptime("03/01/2014", "%d/%m/%Y")},
               {'timestamp': datetime.strptime("01/01/2014", "%d/%m/%Y")},]

date_grouped_objects = OrderedDefaultdict(list)

for obj in sorted(object_list):
    key = obj['timestamp'].strftime("%d/%m/%Y")  # convert datetime to string
    date_grouped_objects[key].append(obj)

for key, value in date_grouped_objects.iteritems():
    print '[{!r}] = {}'.format(key, value)
```

Output:

```
['01/01/2014'] = [{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)},
                  {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)}]
['03/01/2014'] = [{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 3, 0, 0)}]
['12/05/2014'] = [{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 12, 0, 0)}]
```

Comment: You don't need to have it in Python 3.6+. You could just use defaultdict, which is maintaining order of keys by default

Answer (score 8):

Like most Map implementations, [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) isn't ordered<sup>1</sup> and thus itself can't be "sorted".

However, the contained [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) pairings can be sorted and the result is a sequence (list), not a map (dict). This iterable of tuples, where the sort key comes first, can be sorted trivially because or the default-ordering imposed by tuples is established pair-wise from the left.

```
d = {'c': 1, 'a': 2, 'b': 3}
s = sorted(d.items())
# s -> [('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 1)]
```

For more complex cases, a custom comparison function or a key selector function can be used [for the sort](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting); these both produce the same output as above.

```
s = sorted(d.items(), lambda a, b: a[0] >= b[0])
s = sorted(d.items(), key = lambda i: i[0])
```

<sup>1</sup>An [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) could be used to maintain the insertion-ordering, once the keys are sorted.

> An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted..

However, I do not recommend basing algorithms on this special guarantee.

```
import collections
od = collections.OrderedDict(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin sorted method. It works for both values and keys. You can use the key and reverse arguments for complex sorts