# Reading thru CSV file, finding columns with same value and appending their other column values

Tags: python, csv

quick logic question.

If I have a CSV file that has a dictionary value for each line (with columns being ["Location"], ["Movie Title"], ["Date"]), what's the best way for me to combined the Title and Date values of data rows with the same Location value?

snippet of data:

```
Location    Movie Title Date    
Edgebrook Park, Chicago     A League of Their Own   7-Jun   
Edgebrook Park, Chicago     It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World 9-Jun
```

For every row that has the same location (^as in this example), i'd like to make an output like this so that there are no duplicate locations.

```
Edgebrook Park, Chicago     A League of Their Own   7-Jun    It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World    9-Jun
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

**UPDATE:**
I've had to change the data a little bit, so now my columns are looking like:

```
Location,MovieDate,Formatted_Address,Lat,Lng
"Edgebrook Park, Chicago ",Jun-7 A League of Their Own,"Edgebrook Park, 6525 North Hiawatha Avenue, Chicago, IL 60646, USA",41.9998876,-87.7627672
"Gage Park, Chicago ","Jun-9 It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World","Gage Park, Chicago, IL, USA",41.7954363,-87.6962257
"Jefferson Memorial Park, Chicago ",Jun-12 Monsters University ,"Jefferson Memorial Park, 4822 North Long Avenue, Chicago, IL 60630, USA",41.76083920000001,-87.6294353
"Commercial Club Playground, Chicago ",Jun-12 Despicable Me 2,"Chicago, IL, USA",41.8781136,-87.6297982
```

and so on. I'm seeing a lot of `OrderedDict` or `defaultdict` suggestions around here, but what's the best way to extend or append just the `'MovieDates'` column now, instead of the entire rest of the row as the value to the `'Location'` column key?

Comment: Could you provide the code you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you plan on doing with the columns but this will group the elements by location

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict()
import csv
with open("in.csv") as f,open("new.csv" ,"w") as out:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    wr= csv.writer(out)
    header = next(r)
    for row in r:
        loc,*rest = row
        od.setdefault(loc, []).extend(rest)
    wr.writerow(header)
    for loc,vals in od.items():
        wr.writerow([loc]+vals)
```

Presumed input:

```
Location    Movie Title Date    
"Edgebrook Park, Chicago","A League of Their Own",7-Jun
"Edgebrook Park, Chicago","It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World", 9-Jun
```

Output:

```
Location    Movie Title Date    
"Edgebrook Park, Chicago",A League of Their Own,7-Jun,"It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World",9-Jun
```

I presume your csv file is actually structured properly and the columns are actually comma delimited, if not then it will get a lot more complicated.

If your format is actually as posted you will have to split yourself:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict()
import csv
import re
with open("in.csv") as f,open("new.csv", "w") as out:
    header = next(f)
    for line in f:
        loc, rest = re.split("\s{2,}",line.rstrip(),1)
        od.setdefault(loc, []).extend(rest)
    out.write(header)
    for loc, vals in od.items():
        out.write("{} ".format(loc))
        out.write(" ".join(vals))
```

Input:

```
Location    Movie Title Date    
Edgebrook Park, Chicago     A League of Their Own   7-Jun   
Edgebrook Park, Chicago     It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World 9-Jun
```

Output:

```
Location    Movie Title Date    
Edgebrook Park, Chicago A League of Their Own   7-Jun It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World 9-Jun
```

If your format is a bit screwed up, I would take the opportunity to try to get it into some format that is more easily parsed.

For python 2:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict()
import csv
with open("in.csv") as f,open("new.csv" ,"w") as out:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    wr= csv.writer(out)
    header = next(r)
    for row in r:
        loc,rest = row[0], row[1:]
        od.setdefault(loc, []).extend(rest)
    wr.writerow(header)
    for loc,vals in od.items():
        wr.writerow([loc]+vals)
```

Comment: `loc,*rest = row` returns invalid syntax for me. is that correct?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce. that is python3 syntax, I will add the python2 equivalent

Comment: thanks Padraic. If my columns are actually longer (https://github.com/yongcho822/Movies-in-the-park/blob/master/MovieDictFormatted.csv) but I still only want to group by location and append just the 'MovieDate' column, why does changing the line of code to `loc,rest = row[0], row[1]` not work?

Comment: i have confirmed by writing `print loc, rest` after setting that line of code^  that loc, rest are indeed set to what we want...

`Paschen Park, Chicago  Jun-29 Stanley Ka Dabba
Jackson Park, Chicago  Jun-30 Jaws 
Ridge Park, Chicago  Jun-30 Jumanji 
Millennium Park, Chicago  Jul-1 Top Gun
Montgomery Ward Park, Chicago  Jul-1 Captain Phillip`` etc..

Comment: Hey @Padraic-Cunningham, i've written out my issue here in a nicer to read format here, would really appreciate just a bit more help. thanks man. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445574/python-ordered-dict-issue

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce,  is your csv actually comma separated?

Comment: it is. https://github.com/yongcho822/Movies-in-the-park/blob/master/MovieDictFormatted.csv

Comment: I will have a look, if you want to remove the other question I will add the code here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78722/discussion-between-spicyclubsauce-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

# rows containing your data
rows = ...

byLocation = defaultdict(list)

for row in rows:
    byLocation[row[0]].append(row[1:])
```

Comment: There will be no order using a defaultdict which may notbe suitable

Comment: The OP didn't mention order as a requirement though

Answer (score 0):

This problem would be easy to solve with an `OrderedDefaultdict` from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4127426/355230) of mine (shown below). It would the be equally easy to output the values associated with each theater location.

```
import collections
import csv

class OrderedDefaultdict(collections.OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not args:
            self.default_factory = None
        else:
            if not (args[0] is None or callable(args[0])):
                raise TypeError('first argument must be callable or None')
            self.default_factory = args[0]
            args = args[1:]
        super(OrderedDefaultdict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __missing__ (self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        self[key] = default = self.default_factory()
        return default

    def __reduce__(self):  # optional, for pickle support
        args = (self.default_factory,) if self.default_factory else ()
        return self.__class__, args, None, None, self.iteritems()

movies = OrderedDefaultdict(list)

with open('movies.csv', 'rb') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in csv_reader:
        movies[row['Location']].append(' '.join([row['Movie Title'], row['Date']]))

import json  # just to display dictionary created
print(json.dumps(movies, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "Edgebrook Park, Chicago": [
        "A League of Their Own 7-Jun",
        "It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World 9-Jun"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
 from collections import defaultdict
 import csv

 ret = defaultdict([])
 f = open("in.csv")
 fread = csv.reader(f)
 for r in fread:
     ret[r[0]].append("{}, {} ".format(r[1], r[2]))
 res = ["{} {}".format(k, "".join(ret[k])) for k in ret]
 print res
 f.close()
```