# python ordered dict issue

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

If I have a CSV file that has a dictionary value for each line (with columns being ["Location"], ["MovieDate"], ["Formatted_Address"], ["Lat"], ["Lng"]), I have been told to use OrderDict if I want to group by `Location` and append on all the `MovieDate` values that share the same `Location` value.

ex of data:

```
Location,MovieDate,Formatted_Address,Lat,Lng
    "Edgebrook Park, Chicago ",Jun-7 A League of Their Own,"Edgebrook Park, 6525 North Hiawatha Avenue, Chicago, IL 60646, USA",41.9998876,-87.7627672
    "Edgebrook Park, Chicago ","Jun-9 It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World","Edgebrook Park, 6525 North Hiawatha Avenue, Chicago, IL 60646, USA",41.9998876,-87.7627672
```

For every row that has the same location (^as in this example), i'd like to make an output like this so that there are no duplicate locations.

```
 "Edgebrook Park, Chicago ","Jun-7 A League of Their Own Jun-9 It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World","Edgebrook Park, 6525 North Hiawatha Avenue, Chicago, IL 60646, USA",41.9998876,-87.7627672
```

What's wrong with my code using ordereddict to do this?

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict()
import csv
with open("MovieDictFormatted.csv") as f,open("MoviesCombined.csv" ,"w") as out:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    header = next(r)
    for row in r:
        loc,rest = row[0], row[1]
        od.setdefault(loc, []).append(rest)
    wr.writerow(header)
    for loc,vals in od.items():
        wr.writerow([loc]+vals)
```

What I end up with is something like this:

```
['Edgebrook Park, Chicago ', 'Jun-7 A League of Their Own']
['Gage Park, Chicago ', "Jun-9 It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World"]
['Jefferson Memorial Park, Chicago ', 'Jun-12 Monsters University ', 'Jul-11 Frozen ', 'Aug-8 The Blues Brothers ']
['Commercial Club Playground, Chicago ', 'Jun-12 Despicable Me 2']
```

The issue is that I'm not getting the other columns to show up in this case, how would I best do that? I would also prefer to make the MovieDate values just one long string as here:
`'Jun-12 Monsters University Jul-11 Frozen Aug-8 The Blues Brothers '`
instead of :

```
'Jun-12 Monsters University ', 'Jul-11 Frozen ', 'Aug-8 The Blues Brothers '
```

thanks guys, appreciate it. I'm a python noob.

Changing `row[0], row[1]` to `row[0], row[1:]` unfortunately doesn't give me what I want.. I only want to be adding the values in the second column (MovieDate), not replicating all the other columns as such:

```
['Jefferson Memorial Park, Chicago ', ['Jun-12 Monsters University ', 'Jefferson Memorial Park, 4822 North Long Avenue, Chicago, IL 60630, USA', '41.76083920000001', '-87.6294353'], ['Jul-11 Frozen ', 'Jefferson Memorial Park, 4822 North Long Avenue, Chicago, IL 60630, USA', '41.76083920000001', '-87.6294353'], ['Aug-8 The Blues Brothers ', 'Jefferson Memorial Park, 4822 North Long Avenue, Chicago, IL 60630, USA', '41.76083920000001', '-87.6294353']]
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? Do you get incorrect output? Do you get an error message? We need more detail.

Comment: hey @user2357112,  i updated it - sorry for the incomplete question.

Comment: Is `rest` supposed to be the whole rest of the row? Because `row[1]` is just the thing in the second column.

Comment: yeah, that's a misleading title that i'll change. row[1] is correct and the only thing we want to be appending.

Comment: If you only ever store `row[0]` and `row[1]`, why do you expect any of the data in the other columns to show up in the output?

Comment: well, is there a way to just add up the second column values when grouping by the first column while maintaining/adding on the other columns?

Comment: You'll have to incorporate the other columns into the key or value somehow. It depends on how you want to handle rows with the same first column and conflicting values after the second column.

Comment: because the other columns are just geocode values for the first column (Location), there will never be a case where values will conflict after the second column if the first column value is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a couple of changes, you need to join the lat and long,to remove the dupe lat and longs we need to also use that as the key:

```
with open("data.csv") as f,open("new.csv" ,"w") as out:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    wr= csv.writer(out)
    header = next(r)
    for row in r:
        od.setdefault((row[0], row[-2], row[-1]), []).append(" ".join(row[1:-2]))
    wr.writerow(header)
    for loc,vals in od.items():
        wr.writerow([loc[0]] + vals+list(loc[1:]))
```

Output:

```
Location,MovieDate,Formatted_Address,Lat,Lng
"Edgebrook Park, Chicago ","Jun-7 A League of Their Own Edgebrook Park, 6525 North Hiawatha Avenue, Chicago, IL 60646, USA","Jun-9 It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World Edgebrook Park, 6525 North Hiawatha Avenue, Chicago, IL 60646, USA",41.9998876,-87.7627672
```

`A League of Their Own` is first because it comes before the mad,mad line,
`row[1:-2]` gets everything bar the lat,long and location, we store the lat and long in our key tuple to avoid duplicating writing it at the end of each row.

Using names and unpacking might make it a little easier to follow:

```
with open("data.csv") as f, open("new.csv", "w") as out:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    header = next(r)
    for row in r:
        loc, mov, form, lat, long = row
        od.setdefault((loc, lat, long), []).append("{} {}".format(mov, form))
    wr.writerow(header)
    for loc, vals in od.items():
        wr.writerow([loc[0]] + vals + list(loc[1:]))
```

Using csv.Dictwriter to keep five columns:

```
od = OrderedDict()
import csv

with open("data.csv") as f, open("new.csv", "w") as out:
    r = csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames=['Location', 'MovieDate', 'Formatted_Address', 'Lat', 'Lng'])
    wr = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=r.fieldnames)
    for row in r:
        od.setdefault(row["Location"], dict(Location=row["Location"], Lat=row["Lat"], Lng=row["Lng"],
                                        MovieDate=[], Formatted_Address=row["Formatted_Address"]))

        od[row["Location"]]["MovieDate"].append(row["MovieDate"])
    for loc, vals in od.items():
        od[loc]["MovieDate"]= ", ".join(od[loc]["MovieDate"])
        wr.writerow(vals)
```

#
Output:

```
"Edgebrook Park, Chicago ","Jun-7 A League of Their Own, Jun-9 It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World","Edgebrook Park, 6525 North Hiawatha Avenue, Chicago, IL 60646, USA",41.9998876,-87.7627672
```

So the five columns remain intact, we joined the `"MovieDate"` into single strings and `Formatted_Address=form` is always unique so we don't need to update that.

It turns out to match what you wanted all we needed to do was concatenate the `MovieDate's` and remove duplicate entries for Location, Lat, Lng and `'Formatted_Address'`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try changing

```
od.setdefault(loc, []).append(rest)
```

To

```
od[loc] = ' '.join([od.get(loc, ''), ' 'join(rest)])
```

And then keep this as is:

```
wr.writerow([loc]+vals)
```

Comment: with that though, I'm getting the other columns replicated as well:

['Jefferson Memorial Park, Chicago ', ['Jun-12 Monsters University ', 'Jefferson Memorial Park, 4822 North Long Avenue, Chicago, IL 60630, USA', '41.76083920000001', '-87.6294353'], ['Jul-11 Frozen ', 'Jefferson Memorial Park, 4822 North Long Avenue, Chicago, IL 60630, USA', '41.76083920000001', '-87.6294353'], ['Aug-8 The Blues Brothers ', 'Jefferson Memorial Park, 4822 North Long Avenue, Chicago, IL 60630, USA', '41.76083920000001', '-87.6294353']]

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I think you're asking. Let me know how that works out. Thanks!

Comment: hey @Misandrist that's no good unfortunately. shoots this back: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found`

Comment: I've changed the answer again to do the concatenation when adding to the dictionary initially. Let's see how that works.

Comment: damn, same error Misandrist. `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, list found`

Comment: Ok, one more quick change.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming location is the first item of the row:

```
dict = {}
for line in f:
    if line[0] not in dict:
        dict[line[0]] = []
    dict[line[0]].append(line[1:])
```

And for every location, you have the entire rest of the row

```
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    out.write(key + value)
```