# Defaultdict appending trick

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file where elements are stored in two column like the following:

```
 a 1,a 3,a 4,b 1,b 2,b 3,b 4,c 1,c 2.... etc
```

The file contains two columns, one is the key `a`,`b`,`c` etc, and the other is the elements `1`,`2`,`3`,`4` etc.

I stored these items using defaultdict and appended them.
The items in the default dict are:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, `{'a': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'], 'c': ['1', '2'], 'b': ['1', '2', '3', '4']}`)
```

I used following command:

```
from collections import defaultdict
positions = defaultdict(list)

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       sob = line.split()
       key=sob[0]
       ele=sob[1]
       positions[key].append(ele)
    print positions
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I want the defaultdict to be: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, `{'a': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'], 'b': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'c': ['1', '2']}`)

Comment: @SurachitSarkar check my solution

Comment: @SurachitSarkar, so, you want to keep the order of keys?

Comment: Dictionaries (and `defaultdict`s) key's have no specific order, so what you got _is_ what you want. You need an [`OrderedDefaultDict`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126348/how-do-i-rewrite-this-function-to-implement-ordereddict/4127426#4127426).

Comment: @martineu can I do this with other techniques??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insted of defaultdict you can use OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict
positions = OrderedDict()
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, ele = line.strip().split()
        positions[key] = positions.get(key, []) + [ele]
print positions
```

Comment: hey,there is only two column in the file  no commas,I wrote the lines separated by comma.

Comment: @SurachitSarkar, now my code should will work for you

Comment: the problem is when I append key c it is coming in middle of a and b