# Python equivalent for C++ STL vector/list containers

Tags: c++, python, list, vector, containers

Is there something similar in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) that I would use for a container that's like a vector and a list?

Any links would be helpful too.

Comment: For linked list: `[a0,[a1,[a2,[a3,[...]]]]]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the inbuilt list - underlying implementation is similar to C++ vector. Although some things differ - for example, you can put objects of different type in one and the same list.

http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm

**N.B.:** Please keep in mind that vector and list are two **very different** data structures. List are heterogeneous, i.e. can store different object types, while C++ vectors are homogeneous. The data in vectors is stored in ***linear arrangement*** whereas in *list is a collection of references* to the type and the memory address of the variables.

Comment: Is accessing linear in time O(1), similar to accessing a vector as an array in C++?

Comment: Yes, underlying implementation is like a C++ vector.

Comment: That arrays are called lists (which is genereally used as shortcut for linked list, which is a wholly different data structure) is one of the few really unfortunate things in Python.

Comment: Thanks, it has the performance factors on the bottom, good info!

Comment: This answer is incomplete for being accepted: the list class is nothing like std::list.  (There's no builtin linked list implementation in Python.)

Comment: Dead link. Could you provide another?

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at Python's [datastructures](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) page.  Here's a rough translation:

1. () => boost::Tuple (with one important distinction, you can't reassign values in a Python tuple)
2. [] => std::vector (as the comments have aluded towards, lacks memory characteristics associated with vectors)
3. [] => std::list
4. {} => tr1::unordered_map or boost::unordered_map (essentially a hash table)
5. set() => std::set

Comment: Well, it can be... it depends on the backing implementation. But in CPython, yes, `[]` != `std::list`.

Comment: @Amber: No Python implementation would ever dare to use linked lists for the builtin `list` type. That would totally screw about every piece of code that relies on indexing being O(1) (a totally valid assumption) - i.e. really much. We can safely ignore this scenario.

Comment: @delnan There are, however, backing data structures which would be much closer to a `std::list` than the CPython implementation.

Comment: @Amber: Please elaborate. What data structure is "close to a linked list" but offers e.g. O(1) indexing and appending?

Comment: @delnan Certain variants of b-trees don't offer O(1) indexing, but can get fairly close (close enough that all but the largest edge cases wouldn't have a noticeable difference).

Comment: @Amber: In reality it would be a big difference both in terms of performance and memory use, to the worse. So I don't see why anyone would want to differ from CPython in this case - after all, it's the de facto standard.

Comment: `set() => std::unordered_set` , since it's hashset

Answer (score 7):

| py | cpp |
| --- | --- |
| deque | deque |
| PriorityQueue (or you may use heapq) | priorityqueue |
| set | unordered_set |
| list | vector |
| defaultdict(int) | unordered_map |
| list | stack |
| deque | queue |
| dict .get(val,0) | unordered_map |
| [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) | [array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) |
| [np.array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) | [valarray](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) |

> valarray is poor man's np.array.

> in py >= 3.7, dict remember insert order. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777540/13040423

---

In case you need TreeMap / TreeSet

https://github.com/grantjenks/python-sortedcontainers

Answer (score 1):

The `cstl` library wrapped commonly used C++ STL libraries including `vector`, `unordered_map`, and `unordered_set` for Python. It uses purely C++ implementation and does not have the copy-on-write issue that happens in all python objects. See
https://github.com/fuzihaofzh/cstl for how to install and use.

Install it from pip

```bash
pip install cstl
```

Convert python objects into cstl objects:

```py
import cstl

# Directly covert containers from python
v = cstl.frompy({"1":[1,2,3], "2":[4,5,6]}) # convert python object to cstl object
v["1"][2] = 10 # access cstl object
pv = cstl.topy(v) # convert cstl object to python object 
print(pv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists are sequences.

see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

append is like push_back, see the other methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

Python also has as part of the standard library an [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) type which is more efficient and the member type is constrained.

You may also look at [numpy](https://numpy.org/) (not part of the standard library) if you need to get serious about efficient manipulation of large vectors/arrays.