# subclassing from OrderedDict and defaultdict

Tags: python, collections, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

Raymond Hettinger [showed](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) a really cool way to combine collection classes:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
  pass
# if pickle support is desired, see original post
```

I want to do something similar for OrderedDict and defaultdict. But of course, defaultdict has a different `__init__` signature, so it requires extra work. What's the cleanest way to solve this problem? I use Python 3.3.

I found a good solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4127426/336527, but I was thinking maybe deriving from defaultdict might make this even simpler?

Comment: While we're on the topic, can someone explain to me how the OrderedDict example actually gets OrderedDict functionality without any explicit `super`-delegation to that class? Is it because of `super` calls somewhere within `Counter` that get re-routed through `OrderedDict` instead of going to `dict` directly as they ordinarily would? Or just what?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You mean `OrderedCounter`, but good question.

Comment: @agf er, yes, exactly. Stupid edit timeout... :(

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think the answer is that `Counter` doesn't implement any of the `dict` methods that `OrderedDict` needs to implement to work, and `dict` is the base class of both `Counter` and `OrderedDict`, so normal calls on the instance to those methods in either `OrderedCounter` or `Counter` get delegated to `OrderedDict`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I do an ordered, default dict in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190331/can-i-do-an-ordered-default-dict-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inheriting from `OrderedDict` as in the answer you linked to is the simplest way. It is more work to implement an ordered store than it is to get default values from a factory function.

All you need to implement for `defaultdict` is a bit of custom `__init__` logic and the extremely simple `__missing__`.

If you instead inherit from `defaultdict`, you have to delegate to or re-implement at least `__setitem__`, `__delitem__` and `__iter__` to reproduce the in-order operation. You still have to do setup work in `__init__`, though you might be able to inherit or simply leave out some of the other methods depending on your needs.

Take a look at [the original recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/) or [any of the others linked to from another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848/how-do-you-retrieve-items-from-a-dictionary-in-the-order-that-theyre-inserted) for what that would entail.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a way to subclass them both, but not sure if there are bugs:

```
class OrderedDefaultDict(defaultdict, OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, default, *args, **kwargs):
        defaultdict.__init__(self, default)
        OrderedDict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```