# Does Dictionary in Python always arranges keys in ascending order?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has frequency (int) as keys and numbers (list) as values. If I iterate through the list as given below will it give the frequencies in ascending order.

```
for freq in dic:
   print(freq)
```

Will the frequency be in ascending order?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you retrieve items from a dictionary in the order that they're inserted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848/how-do-you-retrieve-items-from-a-dictionary-in-the-order-that-theyre-inserted)

Comment: This depends on your version of Python. If you're using Python 3.7+ `dicts` are ordered by insertion. If earlier, you need to use `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: Generally, we shouldn't keep in mind that thought for default data structures because it might be changed in the future and nothing guarantees.

Comment: @TuanChau the fact that iteration order is the same as insertion order for `dict` is now a guaranteed property of CPython and will not be changing.  It only becomes an issue if you're using an older version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the items were inserted into the dict in sorted order, recent versions of Python will maintain that order.  If you really need to be sure, it's easy to sort them:

```
for freq in sorted(dic.items()):
   print(freq)
```